# Pandas: create two new columns in a dataframe with values calculated from a pre-existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library and I want to add two new columns to a dataframe `df` with n columns (n > 0).
These new columns result from the application of a function to one of the columns in the dataframe.

The function to apply is like:

```
def calculate(x):
    ...operate...
    return z, y
```

One method for creating a new column for a function returning only a value is:

```
df['new_col']) = df['column_A'].map(a_function)
```

So, what I want, and tried unsuccesfully (*), is something like:

```
(df['new_col_zetas'], df['new_col_ys']) = df['column_A'].map(calculate)
```

What the best way to accomplish this could be ? I scanned the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) with no clue.

**`df['column_A'].map(calculate)` returns a pandas Series each item consisting of a tuple z, y. And trying to assign this to two dataframe columns produces a ValueError.*

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I'd just use `zip`:

```
In [1]: from pandas import *

In [2]: def calculate(x):
   ...:     return x*2, x*3
   ...: 

In [3]: df = DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]})

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

In [5]: df["A1"], df["A2"] = zip(*df["a"].map(calculate))

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   a  b  A1  A2
0  1  2   2   3
1  2  3   4   6
2  3  4   6   9
```

Comment: Thanks, great, it works. I found nothing like this in the docs for 0.8.1... I suppose I should always think on Series as lists of tuples...

Comment: Is there any difference wrt performance on doing this instead ?   zip(*map(calculate,df["a"])) instead of  zip(*df["a"].map(calculate)), which also gives(as above) [(2, 4, 6), (3, 6, 9)]  ?

Comment: I get following warning when doing new column creation like that: "SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead." Should I be worried about that? pandas v.0.15

Answer (score 55):

The top answer is flawed in my opinion. Hopefully, no one is mass importing all of pandas into their namespace with `from pandas import *`. Also, the `map` method should be reserved for those times when passing it a dictionary or Series. It can take a function but this is what `apply` is used for.

So, if you must use the above approach, I would write it like this

```
df["A1"], df["A2"] = zip(*df["a"].apply(calculate))
```

There's actually no reason to use zip here. You can simply do this:

```
df["A1"], df["A2"] = calculate(df['a'])
```

This second method is also much faster on larger DataFrames

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3] * 100000, 'b': [2,3,4] * 100000})
```

DataFrame created with 300,000 rows

```
%timeit df["A1"], df["A2"] = calculate(df['a'])
2.65 ms ± 92.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df["A1"], df["A2"] = zip(*df["a"].apply(calculate))
159 ms ± 5.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

60x faster than zip

---

### In general, avoid using apply

Apply is generally not much faster than iterating over a Python list. Let's test the performance of a for-loop to do the same thing as above

```
%%timeit
A1, A2 = [], []
for val in df['a']:
    A1.append(val**2)
    A2.append(val**3)

df['A1'] = A1
df['A2'] = A2

298 ms ± 7.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So this is twice as slow which isn't a terrible performance regression, but if we cythonize the above, we get much better performance. Assuming, you are using ipython:

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython
cpdef power(vals):
    A1, A2 = [], []
    cdef double val
    for val in vals:
        A1.append(val**2)
        A2.append(val**3)

    return A1, A2

%timeit df['A1'], df['A2'] = power(df['a'])
72.7 ms ± 2.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

#### Directly assigning without apply

You can get even greater speed improvements if you use the direct vectorized operations.

```
%timeit df['A1'], df['A2'] = df['a'] ** 2, df['a'] ** 3
5.13 ms ± 320 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This takes advantage of NumPy's extremely fast vectorized operations instead of our loops. We now have a 30x speedup over the original.

---

### The simplest speed test with `apply`

The above example should clearly show how slow `apply` can be, but just so its extra clear let's look at the most basic example. Let's square a Series of 10 million numbers with and without apply

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10000000))

%timeit s.apply(calc)
3.3 s ± 57.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Without apply is 50x faster

```
%timeit s ** 2
66 ms ± 2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a really great answer. I wanted to ask: what do you think of `applymap` for the case when you have to implement an specific function to each element of the dataframe?

Comment: While there's some good advice in this answer, I believe the main advice to use `func(series)` instead of `series.apply(func)` is only applicable when the func is wholly defined using operations that behave similarly on both an individual value and on a Series. That is the case in the example in the first answer, but it's not the case in the OP's question, which is asking more generally about applying functions to columns. 1/2

Comment: As an example, if df is:
`DataFrame({'a': ['Aaron', 'Bert', 'Christopher'], 'b': ['Bold', 'Courageous', 'Distrusted']})`
and `calc` is:
`def calc(x): return x[0], len(x)`
then `tdf.a.apply(calc))` and `calc(tdf.a)` return very different things.

Comment: @Graham Lea It's true but you can always(maybe or maybe not) vectorize the function. I tried and it works fine`tdf['A1'], tdf['A2'] = np.vectorize(calc)(tdf.a)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
df['new_col1'], df['new_col2'] = df['column_A'].pipe(calculate)
```