# How to look back at previous rows from within Pandas dataframe function call?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, algorithmic-trading, quantitative-finance

I am researching/backtesting a trading system.

I have a Pandas dataframe containing OHLC data and have added several [calculated columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376863/adding-calculated-columns-to-a-dataframe-in-pandas) which identify price patterns that I will use as signals to initiate positions.

I would now like to add a further column that will keep track of the current net position. I have tried using df.apply(), but passing the dataframe itself as the argument instead of the row object, as with the latter I seem to be unable to look back at previous rows to determine whether they resulted in any price patterns:

```
open_campaigns = []
Campaign = namedtuple('Campaign', 'open position stop')

def calc_position(df):
  # sum of current positions + any new positions

  if entered_long(df):
    open_campaigns.add(
        Campaign(
            calc_long_open(df.High.shift(1)), 
            calc_position_size(df), 
            calc_long_isl(df)
        )
    )

  return sum(campaign.position for campaign in open_campaigns)

def entered_long(df):
  return buy_pattern(df) & (df.High > df.High.shift(1))

df["Position"] = df.apply(lambda row: calc_position(df), axis=1)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()', u'occurred at index 1997-07-16 08:00:00')
```

Rolling window functions would seem to be the natural fit, but as I understand it, they only act on a single time series or column, so wouldn't work either as I need to access the values of multiple columns at multiple timepoints.

How should I in fact be doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has its roots in NumPy.

```
def entered_long(df):
  return buy_pattern(df) & (df.High > df.High.shift(1))
```

`entered_long` is returning an array-like object. NumPy refuses to guess if an array is True or False:

```
In [48]: x = np.array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [49]: bool(x)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

To fix this, use `any` or `all` to specify what you mean for an array to be True:

```
def calc_position(df):
  # sum of current positions + any new positions

  if entered_long(df).any():  # or .all()
```

The `any()` method will return True if any of the items in `entered_long(df)` are True.
The `all()` method will return True if all the items in `entered_long(df)` are True.

Comment: It really was staring me in the face... Thanks :)