# How to determine the row of a particular record in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Dataframe:

```
data = {'level1':[20,19,20,21,25,29,30,31,30,29,31],
        'level2': [10,10,20,20,20,10,10,20,20,10,10]}
index = pd.date_range('12/1/2014', periods=11)
frame = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

In [75]: frame
Out[75]:
level1  level2
2014-12-01  20  10
2014-12-02  19  10
2014-12-03  20  20
2014-12-04  21  20
2014-12-05  25  20
2014-12-06  29  10
2014-12-07  30  10
2014-12-08  31  20
2014-12-09  30  20
2014-12-10  29  10
2014-12-11  31  10
```

I would like to take a "cell" of this frame, and find out which row it is in.

In other words, `frame.level1[4]."rownumber"()`?

What  is the integer row number? The desired answer would be 4

Note: I am aware this is circular, the ultimate goal is to put this into a formula to pick up another "cell" using relative navigation, e.g.

```
#pseudocode
def rowgetter(x)
    priorvalue =frame.at[index[rownumber(x)-1],'level1']#pseudocode
    priorvalue += 10 #or something

and then
rownmums=frame.level1.map(rowgetter)
```

Result would look like

```
nan(?)
30
29
30
31
35
39
40
41
40
39
```

---

The reason I'm asking this is that I can't [get shift to work in a formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28372847/why-cant-i-apply-shift-from-within-a-pandas-function), but even if the question in the link is answered, I find this question interesting enough by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `argwhere`:

```
In [11]: np.argwhere((frame.level1 == 25).values)[0][0]
Out[11]: 4
```

or `argmax`:

```
In [12]: np.argmax((frame.level1 == 25).values)
Out[12]: 4
```

Note: this wouldn't raise if no match was found, but you could wrap it in something to check (that the value at this position was 25).

*I don't think there's a way to lookup a specific value without == (I guess it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432112/1240268).*

Comment: Thanks Andy, but my need is slightly different, I am not going to pass in the actual value (e.g. 25) but the data frame element, and all inside a function. I added that to the question, maybe it wasn't clear. the other issue is that my values are not unique, so I couldn't look up the unique row for the value 30 in my example (as it is twice in frame.level1)