# Shift happens: using pandas shift to combine rows

Tags: pandas

I am trying to add a column to my data frame in pandas where each entry represents the difference between another column's values across two adjacent rows (if certain conditions are met). Following this answer to [get previous row's value and calculate new column pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22082596/575530) I'm using [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to find the delta between the `duration_seconds` column entries in the two rows (next minus current) and then return that delta as the derived entry if both rows are from the same `user_id`, the next row's `action` is not 'login', and the delta is not negative. Here's the code:

```python
def duration (row):
    candidate_duration = row['duration_seconds'].shift(-1) - row['duration_seconds']
    if row['user_id'] == row['user_id'].shift(-1) and row['action'].shift(-1) != 'login' and candidate_duration >= 0:
        return candidate_duration
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Then I test the function using

```python
analytic_events.apply(lambda row: duration(row), axis = 1)
```

But that throws an error:

> AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 9464384')

I wondered if this was akin to the error fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28375288/575530) and so I tried passing in the whole data frame thus:

```python
duration(analytic_events)
```

but that throws the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What should I be doing to achieve this combination; how should I be using `shift`?

Comment: Is it possible add an example dataframe and expected output?

Comment: I was hoping it would be self explanatory without that @Erfan, it is probably a stupid mistake I am making. But I can try (the real data is enormous and private)

Comment: samples data always help understanding the statements. :)

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your data. You could simplify this with using conditionally creation of columns with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cond1 = analytic_events['user_id'] == analytic_events['user_id'].shift(-1)   
cond2 = analytic_events['action'].shift(-1) != 'login'
cond3 = analytic_events['duration_seconds'].shift(-1) - analytic_events['duration_seconds'] >= 0

analytic_events['candidate_duration'] = np.where((cond1) & (cond2) & (cond3), 
                                                 analytic_events['duration_seconds'].shift(-1) - analytic_events['duration_seconds'], 
                                                 np.NaN)
```

**explanation**
`np.where` works as following: `np.where(condition, value if true, value is false)`

Comment: Hmmm. When you say "simplify" you could have said "fix". I'm not sure why yours works and my original doesn't. (N.B. My take away—again—is don't use `apply`!)