# Ranking algorithms in python

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, dataframe, ranking

I have a pandas dataFrame that consist of the following:

```
Athlete A         Athlete  B     Athlete C
speed=10          speed=12       speed=6
endurance=60      endurance=59   endurance=64
```

I would like to rank the strength of those three Athletes based on their speed and endurance. I would like to give a slightly greater weight (0.6) to the endurance. Is there any python library to do rankings based on multiple conditions?

Comment: You can just add a column for speed and endurance and then do sum 0.6 * weight + speed and rank on this, please show your efforts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding calculated column(s) to a dataframe in pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376863/adding-calculated-columns-to-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Answer (score 6):

You should add a new column to your dataframe with the calculated order and then sort it by that column. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Athlete': ['A','B','C'],
                   'Speed': [10,12,6],
                   'Endurance': [60,59,64]})

df['sorting_column'] = df.Speed*0.4 + df.Endurance*0.6 #I think you want 40% speed and 60% endurance right?
df.sort(columns='sorting_column')
```

Result:

```
  Athlete  Endurance  Speed  sorting_column
2       C         64      6            29.2
0       A         60     10            30.0
1       B         59     12            30.8
```

Comment: It works, but I think may be we can normalize speed and endurance first before making the new column.