# Apply function to each row of pandas dataframe to create two new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, `st` containing multiple columns:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 53732 entries, 1993-01-07 12:23:58 to 2012-12-02 20:06:23
Data columns:
Date(dd-mm-yy)_Time(hh-mm-ss)       53732  non-null values
Julian_Day                          53732  non-null values
AOT_1020                            53716  non-null values
AOT_870                             53732  non-null values
AOT_675                             53188  non-null values
AOT_500                             51687  non-null values
AOT_440                             53727  non-null values
AOT_380                             51864  non-null values
AOT_340                             52852  non-null values
Water(cm)                           51687  non-null values
%TripletVar_1020                    53710  non-null values
%TripletVar_870                     53726  non-null values
%TripletVar_675                     53182  non-null values
%TripletVar_500                     51683  non-null values
%TripletVar_440                     53721  non-null values
%TripletVar_380                     51860  non-null values
%TripletVar_340                     52846  non-null values
440-870Angstrom                     53732  non-null values
380-500Angstrom                     52253  non-null values
440-675Angstrom                     53732  non-null values
500-870Angstrom                     53732  non-null values
340-440Angstrom                     53277  non-null values
Last_Processing_Date(dd/mm/yyyy)    53732  non-null values
Solar_Zenith_Angle                  53732  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(22), object(1)
```

I want to create two new columns for this dataframe based on applying a function to each row of the dataframe. I don't want to have to call the function multiple times (eg. by doing two separate `apply` calls) as it is rather computationally intensive. I have tried doing this in two ways, and neither of them work:

---

**Using `apply`:**

I have written a function which takes a `Series` and returns a tuple of the values I want:

```
def calculate(s):
    a = s['path'] + 2*s['row'] # Simple calc for example
    b = s['path'] * 0.153
    return (a, b)
```

Trying to apply this to the DataFrame gives an error:

```
st.apply(calculate, axis=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-248-acb7a44054a7> in <module>()
----> 1 st.apply(calculate, axis=1)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, args, **kwds)
   4191                     return self._apply_raw(f, axis)
   4192                 else:
-> 4193                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
   4194             else:
   4195                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures)
   4274                 index = None
   4275 
-> 4276             result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
   4277             result.rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len(res_index)), res_index)),
   4278                           inplace=True)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    390             mgr = self._init_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    391         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 392             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    393         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    394             mask = ma.getmaskarray(data)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    521 
    522         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns,
--> 523                               dtype=dtype)
    524 
    525     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None,

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5411 
   5412     # consolidate for now
-> 5413     mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)
   5414     return mgr.consolidate()
   5415 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in __init__(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check)
    802 
    803         if do_integrity_check:
--> 804             self._verify_integrity()
    805 
    806         self._consolidate_check()

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in _verify_integrity(self)
    892                                      "items")
    893             if block.values.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
--> 894                 raise AssertionError('Block shape incompatible with manager')
    895         tot_items = sum(len(x.items) for x in self.blocks)
    896         if len(self.items) != tot_items:

AssertionError: Block shape incompatible with manager
```

I was then going to assign the values returned from `apply` to two new columns using the method shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356501/pandas-create-two-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-values-calculated-from-a-pre). However, I can't even get to this point! This all works fine if I just return one value.

---

**Using a loop:**

I first created two new columns of the dataframe and set them to `None`:

```
st['a'] = None
st['b'] = None
```

Then looped over all of the indices and tried to modify these `None` values that I'd got in there, but the modifications I did didn't seem to work. That is, no error was generated, but the DataFrame didn't seem to be modified.

```
for i in st.index:
    # do calc here
    st.ix[i]['a'] = a
    st.ix[i]['b'] = b
```

---

I thought that both of these methods would work, but neither of them did. So, what am I doing wrong here? And what is the best, most 'pythonic' and 'pandaonic' way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To make the first approach work, try returning a Series instead of a tuple (apply is throwing an exception because it doesn't know how to glue the rows back together as the number of columns doesn't match the original frame).

```
def calculate(s):
    a = s['path'] + 2*s['row'] # Simple calc for example
    b = s['path'] * 0.153
    return pd.Series(dict(col1=a, col2=b))
```

The second approach should work if you replace:

```
st.ix[i]['a'] = a
```

with:

```
st.ix[i, 'a'] = a
```

Comment: The solution to the second approach works - thanks :-). However, I can't get the first approach to work. Returning a series works, and I get a 'mini-df' returned, but I can't seem to get the values returned from the `apply` function into the original dataframe. Using `st['a'], st['b'] = st.apply(calculate, axis=1)` doesn't work, and neither does wrapping the right-hand side in `zip(*)`. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You can concatenate the 'mini' df's columns to the original DataFrame with `pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)`.  You may also want to consider column-based operations, rather than row-based, e.g., compute and add column 'a' with `df['a'] = df['path'] + 2 * df['row']`

Answer (score 18):

I always use lambdas and the built-in `map()` function to create new rows by combining other rows:

```
st['a'] = map(lambda path, row: path + 2 * row, st['path'], st['row'])
```

It might be slightly more complicated than necessary for doing linear combinations of numerical columns.  On the other hand, I feel it's good to adopt as a convention as it can be used with more complicated combinations of rows (e.g. working with strings) or filling missing data in a column using functions of the other columns.

For example, lets say you have a table with columns gender, and title, and some of the titles are missing.  You can fill them with a function as follows:

```
title_dict = {'male': 'mr.', 'female': 'ms.'}
table['title'] = map(lambda title,
    gender: title if title != None else title_dict[gender],
    table['title'], table['gender'])
```

Comment: In Python 3 you will need to use `tuple(map(…))` instead of just `map(…)`.

Answer (score 5):

This was solved here:
[Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-which-returns-multiple-values)

Applied to your question this should work:

```
def calculate(s):
    a = s['path'] + 2*s['row'] # Simple calc for example
    b = s['path'] * 0.153
    return pd.Series({'col1': a, 'col2': b})

df = df.merge(df.apply(calculate, axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: This only worked for me if I used: return pd.Series({'col1': a, 'col2': b}), is the = syntax specific to some version of python?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution based on [Assigning New Columns in Method Chains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains):

```
st.assign(a = st['path'] + 2*st['row'], b = st['path'] * 0.153)
```

Be aware `assign` **always** returns a copy of the data, leaving the original DataFrame untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) here:

```
st['a'], st['b'] = st.pipe(calculate)
```