# Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns, return-type

How to do this in pandas:

I have a function `extract_text_features` on a single text column, returning multiple output columns. Specifically, the function returns 6 values.

The function works, however there doesn't seem to be any proper return type (pandas DataFrame/ numpy array/ Python list) such that the output can get correctly assigned `df.ix[: ,10:16] = df.textcol.map(extract_text_features)`

So I think I need to drop back to iterating with `df.iterrows()`, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)?

UPDATE:
Iterating with `df.iterrows()` is at least 20x slower, so I surrendered and split out the function into six distinct `.map(lambda ...)` calls.

UPDATE 2: this question was asked back around [v0.11.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases?after=v0.13.0_ahl1), before the useability `df.apply` was improved or [`df.assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) was [added in v0.16](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.16.0.html?highlight=assign). Hence much of the question and answers are not too relevant.

Comment: I don't think you can do multiple assignment the way you have it written: `df.ix[: ,10:16]`.  I think you'll have to `merge` your features into the dataset.

Comment: For those wanting a much more performant solution [check this one below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47097625/3707607) which does not use `apply`

Comment: Most numeric operations with pandas can be vectorized - this means they are much faster than conventional iteration. OTOH, some operations (such as string and regex) are inherently hard to vectorize. This this case, it is important to understand _how_ to loop over your data. More more information on when and how looping over your data is to be done, please read [For loops with Pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care/54028200#54028200).

Comment: @coldspeed: the main issue was not choosing which was the higher-performance among several options, it was fighting pandas syntax to get this to work at all, back around [v0.11.0](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/releases?after=v0.13.0_ahl1).

Comment: Indeed, the comment is intended for future readers who're looking for iterative solutions, who either don't know any better, or who know what they're doing.

Comment: Of all answers below, most practical and efficient method I found is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42072756/4617501). This avoids the overhead of `pd.Series` creation for each row which made it work 30x faster in my case.

Comment: @PushkarNimkar: You're neglecting the actual string functions themselves, so it'll be << 30x. But by all means please add your own answer, and benchmark runtime against other approaches.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Building off of user1827356 's answer, you can do the assignment in one pass using `df.merge`:

```
df.merge(df.textcol.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s+1, 'feature2':s-1})), 
    left_index=True, right_index=True)

    textcol  feature1  feature2
0  0.772692  1.772692 -0.227308
1  0.857210  1.857210 -0.142790
2  0.065639  1.065639 -0.934361
3  0.819160  1.819160 -0.180840
4  0.088212  1.088212 -0.911788
```

**EDIT:**
Please be aware of the huge memory consumption and low speed: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/ !

Comment: just out of curiousity, is it expected to use up a lot of memory by doing this? I am doing this on a dataframe that holds 2.5mil rows, and i nearly ran into memory problems (also it is much slower than returning just 1 column).

Comment: 'df.join(df.textcol.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s+1, 'feature2':s-1})))' would be a better option I think.

Comment: @ShivamKThakkar why do you think your suggestion would be a better option? Would it be more efficient you think or have less memory cost?

Comment: Please consider the speed and the memory required: https://ys-l.github.io/posts/2015/08/28/how-not-to-use-pandas-apply/

Comment: Is this still true as of 2023 (the huge memory consumption) ?

Answer (score 295):

I usually do this using `zip`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['num'])
>>> df
    num
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9

>>> def powers(x):
>>>     return x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6

>>> df['p1'], df['p2'], df['p3'], df['p4'], df['p5'], df['p6'] = \
>>>     zip(*df['num'].map(powers))

>>> df
        num     p1      p2      p3      p4      p5      p6
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
2       2       2       4       8       16      32      64
3       3       3       9       27      81      243     729
4       4       4       16      64      256     1024    4096
5       5       5       25      125     625     3125    15625
6       6       6       36      216     1296    7776    46656
7       7       7       49      343     2401    16807   117649
8       8       8       64      512     4096    32768   262144
9       9       9       81      729     6561    59049   531441
```

Comment: But what do you do if you have 50 columns added like this rather than 6?

Comment: @max `temp = list(zip(*df['num'].map(powers))); for i, c in enumerate(columns): df[c] = temp[c]`

Comment: @ostrokach I think you meant `for i, c in enumerate(columns): df[c] = temp[i]`. Thanks to this, I really got the purpose of `enumerate` :D

Comment: This is by far the most elegant and readable solution I've come across for this. Unless you're getting performance problems, the idiom `zip(*df['col'].map(function))` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @rocarvaj while I am adding a comment rather too late, if anyone comes across and realize my mistake I'd appreciate the insight. obviously the two thats posted here don't work, it seems to be `for i, c in enumerate(temp): df[c] = temp[c]`

Comment: @XiaoyuLu See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Answer (score 260):

In 2020, I use `apply()` with argument `result_type='expand'`

```python
applied_df = df.apply(lambda row: fn(row.text), axis='columns', result_type='expand')
df = pd.concat([df, applied_df], axis='columns')
```

`fn()` should return a `dict`; its keys will be the new column names.

Alternatively you can do a one-liner by also specifying the column names:

```python
df[["col1", "col2", ...]] = df.apply(lambda row: fn(row.text), axis='columns', result_type='expand')
```

Comment: That is how you do it, nowadays!

Comment: This worked out of the box in 2020 while many other questions did not. Also it doesn't use `pd.Series`  which is always nice regarding performance issues

Comment: This is a good solution. The only problem is, you can't choose the name for the 2 newly added columns. You need to later do df.rename(columns={0:'col1', 1:'col2'})

Comment: @pedrambashiri If the function you pass to `df.apply` returns a `dict`, the columns will come out named according to the keys.

Comment: This is the best answer! Often you have a situation where from a single dataframe column or series you have to create a dataframe of multiple new columns based on a transformation on the original column/series. The transformation function often returns k-tuples, and these k-tuples must be separated into k columns, based on some order. @Ben's answer clearly does this very neatly. Thanks!

Comment: Also, as pointed out somewhere else here, this was introduced in Pandas 0.23.0. For earlier versions I don' t think there is a really fast way of doing this k-tuple -> k columns transformation.

Comment: The selected answer should be updated to this. Or the question asked again.

Comment: all I needed from this answer was `result_type='expand'`. E.g. `df[new_cols] = df.apply(extract_text_features, axis=1, result_type='expand')` just works. Although you'd need to know names of the new columns.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (fn applied returns a df). Anyone's thoughts?

Comment: @jtlz2 you can't use `apply` with a function that returns a df. `apply` normally returns a single value for each input, looping over each row. This question/answer shows how to return multiple values, but they are still just for one row of the source df, so you should either update your function as such, or skip using `apply` and go a different route (such as iteration followed by `concat`, etc)

Answer (score 94):

This is what I've done in the past

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'textcol' : np.random.rand(5)})

df
    textcol
0  0.626524
1  0.119967
2  0.803650
3  0.100880
4  0.017859

df.textcol.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s+1, 'feature2':s-1}))
   feature1  feature2
0  1.626524 -0.373476
1  1.119967 -0.880033
2  1.803650 -0.196350
3  1.100880 -0.899120
4  1.017859 -0.982141
```

Editing for completeness

```
pd.concat([df, df.textcol.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s+1, 'feature2':s-1}))], axis=1)
    textcol feature1  feature2
0  0.626524 1.626524 -0.373476
1  0.119967 1.119967 -0.880033
2  0.803650 1.803650 -0.196350
3  0.100880 1.100880 -0.899120
4  0.017859 1.017859 -0.982141
```

Comment: concat() looks simpler than merge() for connecting the new cols to the original dataframe.

Comment: nice answer, you don't need to use a dict or a merge if you specify the columns outside of the apply `df[['col1', 'col2']] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series('val1', 'val2'))`

Answer (score 89):

This is the correct and easiest way to accomplish this for 95% of use cases:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[range(10)]), columns=['num'])
>>> df
    num
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5

>>> def example(x):
...     x['p1'] = x['num']**2
...     x['p2'] = x['num']**3
...     x['p3'] = x['num']**4
...     return x

>>> df = df.apply(example, axis=1)
>>> df
    num  p1  p2  p3
0    0   0   0    0
1    1   1   1    1
2    2   4   8   16
3    3   9  27   81
4    4  16  64  256
```

Comment: shouldn't you write: df = df.apply(example(df), axis=1)
correct me if I am wrong, I am just a newbie

Comment: @user299791, No in this case you are treating example as a first class object so you are passing in the function itself. This function will applied to each row.

Comment: hi Michael, your answer helped me in my problem. Definitely your solution is better than the original pandas' df.assign() method, cuz this is one time per column. Using assign(), if you want to create 2 new columns, you have to use df1 to work on df to get new column1, then use df2 to work on df1 to create the second new column...this is quite monotonous. But your method saved my life!!! Thanks!!!

Comment: Won't that run the column assignment code once per row? Wouldn't it be better to return a `pd.Series({k:v})` and serialize the column assignment like in Ewan's answer?

Comment: If it helps anyone, while this approach is correct and also the simplest of all the presented solutions, updating the row directly like this ended up being surprisingly slow - an order of magnitude slower than the apply with 'expand' + pd.concat solutions

Comment: I actually agree that this solution is the most elegant or clean answer so far, should be accepted.

Comment: Making columns before calling apply significantly speeds up the execution. Something like this: example = example.assign(p1=None, p2=None, p3=None)

Answer (score 64):

Just use `result_type="expand"`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(10,2)), columns=["random", "a"])
df[["sq_a","cube_a"]] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.a**2, x.a**3], axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Comment: It helps to point out that option is [new in 0.23](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). The question was asked back on 0.11

Comment: Nice, this is simple and still works neatly. This is the one I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: Duplicates an earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363890/823470

Comment: @tar actually the second line is different and was quite helpful for me to see!

Answer (score 45):

For me this worked:

Input df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col x': [1,2,3]})
   col x
0      1
1      2
2      3
```

Function

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series([x*x, x*x*x])
```

Create 2 new columns:

```
df[['square x', 'cube x']] = df['col x'].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
   col x  square x  cube x
0      1         1       1
1      2         4       8
2      3         9      27
```

Answer (score 23):

**Summary:** If you only want to create a few columns, use `df[['new_col1','new_col2']] = df[['data1','data2']].apply( function_of_your_choosing(x), axis=1)`

For this solution, the number of new columns you are creating must be equal to the number columns you use as input to the .apply() function. If you want to do something else, have a look at the other answers.

**Details**
Let's say you have two-column dataframe. The first column is a person's height when they are 10; the second is said person's height when they are 20.

Suppose you need to calculate both the mean of each person's heights and sum of each person's heights. That's two values per each row.

You could do this via the following, soon-to-be-applied function:

```
def mean_and_sum(x):
    """
    Calculates the mean and sum of two heights.
    Parameters:
    :x -- the values in the row this function is applied to. Could also work on a list or a tuple.
    """

    sum=x[0]+x[1]
    mean=sum/2
    return [mean,sum]
```

You might use this function like so:

```
 df[['height_at_age_10','height_at_age_20']].apply(mean_and_sum(x),axis=1)
```

(To be clear: this apply function takes in the values from each row in the subsetted dataframe and returns a list.)

However, if you do this:

```
df['Mean_&_Sum'] = df[['height_at_age_10','height_at_age_20']].apply(mean_and_sum(x),axis=1)
```

you'll create 1 new column that contains the [mean,sum] lists, which you'd presumably want to avoid, because that would require another Lambda/Apply.

Instead, you want to break out each value into its own column. To do this, you can create two columns at once:

```
df[['Mean','Sum']] = df[['height_at_age_10','height_at_age_20']]
.apply(mean_and_sum(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: For pandas 0.23, you'll need to use the syntax: `df["mean"], df["sum"] = df[['height_at_age_10','height_at_age_20']]
.apply(mean_and_sum(x),axis=1)`

Comment: This function might raise error. The return function must be 
`return pd.Series([mean,sum])`

Answer (score 14):

I've looked several ways of doing this and the method shown here (returning a pandas series) doesn't seem to be most efficient.

If we start with a largeish dataframe of random data:

```
# Setup a dataframe of random numbers and create a 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,3),columns=list('ABC'))
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda r: ':'.join(map(str, (r.A, r.B, r.C))), axis=1)
columns = 'new_a', 'new_b', 'new_c'
```

The example shown here:

```
# Create the dataframe by returning a series
def method_b(v):
    return pd.Series({k: v for k, v in zip(columns, v.split(':'))})
%timeit -n10 -r3 df.D.apply(method_b)
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 2.77 s per loop

An alternative method:

```
# Create a dataframe from a series of tuples
def method_a(v):
    return v.split(':')
%timeit -n10 -r3 pd.DataFrame(df.D.apply(method_a).tolist(), columns=columns)
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 8.85 ms per loop

By my reckoning it's far more efficient to take a series of tuples and then convert that to a DataFrame. I'd be interested to hear people's thinking though if there's an error in my working.

Comment: This is really useful! I got a 30x speed-up compared to function returning series methods.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted solution is going to be extremely slow for lots of data. The solution with the greatest number of upvotes is a little difficult to read and also slow with numeric data. If each new column can be calculated independently of the others, I would just assign each of them directly without using `apply`.

#### Example with fake character data

Create 100,000 strings in a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['he jumped', 'she ran', 'they hiked'],
                                   size=100000, replace=True),
                  columns=['words'])
df.head()
        words
0     she ran
1     she ran
2  they hiked
3  they hiked
4  they hiked
```

Let's say we wanted to extract some text features as done in the original question. For instance, let's extract the first character, count the occurrence of the letter 'e' and capitalize the phrase.

```
df['first'] = df['words'].str[0]
df['count_e'] = df['words'].str.count('e')
df['cap'] = df['words'].str.capitalize()
df.head()
        words first  count_e         cap
0     she ran     s        1     She ran
1     she ran     s        1     She ran
2  they hiked     t        2  They hiked
3  they hiked     t        2  They hiked
4  they hiked     t        2  They hiked
```

**Timings**

```
%%timeit
df['first'] = df['words'].str[0]
df['count_e'] = df['words'].str.count('e')
df['cap'] = df['words'].str.capitalize()
127 ms ± 585 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

def extract_text_features(x):
    return x[0], x.count('e'), x.capitalize()

%timeit df['first'], df['count_e'], df['cap'] = zip(*df['words'].apply(extract_text_features))
101 ms ± 2.96 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Surprisingly, you can get better performance by looping through each value

```
%%timeit
a,b,c = [], [], []
for s in df['words']:
    a.append(s[0]), b.append(s.count('e')), c.append(s.capitalize())

df['first'] = a
df['count_e'] = b
df['cap'] = c
79.1 ms ± 294 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

#### Another example with fake numeric data

Create 1 million random numbers and test the `powers` function from above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000000), columns=['num'])


def powers(x):
    return x, x**2, x**3, x**4, x**5, x**6

%%timeit
df['p1'], df['p2'], df['p3'], df['p4'], df['p5'], df['p6'] = \
       zip(*df['num'].map(powers))
1.35 s ± 83.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Assigning each column is 25x faster and very readable:

```
%%timeit 
df['p1'] = df['num'] ** 1
df['p2'] = df['num'] ** 2
df['p3'] = df['num'] ** 3
df['p4'] = df['num'] ** 4
df['p5'] = df['num'] ** 5
df['p6'] = df['num'] ** 6
51.6 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I made a similar response with [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356501/pandas-create-two-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-values-calculated-from-a-pre/47102054#47102054) on why `apply` is typically not the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Have posted the same answer in two other similar questions. The way I prefer to do this is to wrap up the return values of the function in a series:

```
def f(x):
    return pd.Series([x**2, x**3])
```

And then use apply as follows to create separate columns:

```
df[['x**2','x**3']] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row['x']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def extract_text_features(feature):
    ...
    ...
    return pd.Series((feature1, feature2)) 

df[['NewFeature1', 'NewFeature1']] = df[['feature']].apply(extract_text_features, axis=1)
```

Here the a dataframe with a single feature is being converted to two new features.
Give this a try too.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
future = pd.DataFrame(
    pd.date_range('2022-09-01',periods=360),
    columns=['date']
)

def featurize(datetime):
    return pd.Series({
        'month':datetime.month,
        'year':datetime.year,
        'dayofweek':datetime.dayofweek,
        'dayofyear':datetime.dayofyear
    })
    
future.loc[
    :,['month','year','dayofweek','dayofyear']
    ] = future.date.apply(featurize)

future.head()
```

Output:

```
    date    month   year    dayofweek   dayofyear
0   2022-09-01  9   2022    3           244
1   2022-09-02  9   2022    4           245
2   2022-09-03  9   2022    5           246
3   2022-09-04  9   2022    6           247
4   2022-09-05  9   2022    0           248
```

Comment: Neat. I had asked the original question back on pandas 0.11, what's the earliest pandas version this works on? Which version syntax enhances does it rely on?

Comment: I've personally only tested this on my current version of pandas, which is pandas==1.4.3 but I think it should be pretty compatible with older versions. It looks like '.loc' was around in 0.11: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0/whatsnew/v0.11.0.html

Comment: I think the key is creating a Series from a dictionary that matches the column labels

Answer (score 1):

you can return the entire row instead of values:

```
df = df.apply(extract_text_features,axis = 1)
```

where the function returns the row

```
def extract_text_features(row):
      row['new_col1'] = value1
      row['new_col2'] = value2
      return row
```

Comment: No I don't want to apply `extract_text_features` to every column of the df, only  to the text column `df.textcol`

Answer (score 0):

I have a more complicated situation, the dataset has a nested structure:

```
import json
data = '{"TextID":{"0":"0038f0569e","1":"003eb6998d","2":"006da49ea0"},"Summary":{"0":{"Crisis_Level":["c"],"Type":["d"],"Special_Date":["a"]},"1":{"Crisis_Level":["d"],"Type":["a","d"],"Special_Date":["a"]},"2":{"Crisis_Level":["d"],"Type":["a"],"Special_Date":["a"]}}}'
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(data))
print(df)
```

output:

```
        TextID                                            Summary
0  0038f0569e  {'Crisis_Level': ['c'], 'Type': ['d'], 'Specia...
1  003eb6998d  {'Crisis_Level': ['d'], 'Type': ['a', 'd'], 'S...
2  006da49ea0  {'Crisis_Level': ['d'], 'Type': ['a'], 'Specia...
```

The `Summary` column contains dict objects, so I use `apply` with `from_dict` and `stack` to extract each row of dict:

```
df2 = df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x[1], orient='index').stack(), axis=1)
print(df2)
```

output:

```
    Crisis_Level Special_Date Type     
                0            0    0    1
0            c            a    d  NaN
1            d            a    a    d
2            d            a    a  NaN
```

Looks good, but missing the `TextID` column. To get `TextID` column back, I've tried three approach:

1. Modify `apply` to return multiple columns:

   ```
   df_tmp = df.copy()

   df_tmp[['TextID', 'Summary']] = df.apply(
       lambda x: pd.Series([x[0], pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x[1], orient='index').stack()]), axis=1)
   print(df_tmp)
   ```

   output:

   ```
       TextID                                            Summary
   0  0038f0569e  Crisis_Level  0    c
   Type          0    d
   Spec...
   1  003eb6998d  Crisis_Level  0    d
   Type          0    a
       ...
   2  006da49ea0  Crisis_Level  0    d
   Type          0    a
   Spec...
   ```

   But this is not what I want, the `Summary` structure are flatten.
2. Use `pd.concat`:

   ```
   df_tmp2 = pd.concat([df['TextID'], df2], axis=1)
   print(df_tmp2)
   ```

   output:

   ```
       TextID (Crisis_Level, 0) (Special_Date, 0) (Type, 0) (Type, 1)
   0  0038f0569e                 c                 a         d       NaN
   1  003eb6998d                 d                 a         a         d
   2  006da49ea0                 d                 a         a       NaN
   ```

   Looks fine, the `MultiIndex` column structure are preserved as tuple. But check columns type:

   ```
   df_tmp2.columns
   ```

   output:

   ```
   Index(['TextID', ('Crisis_Level', 0), ('Special_Date', 0), ('Type', 0),
       ('Type', 1)],
       dtype='object')
   ```

   Just as a regular `Index` class, not `MultiIndex` class.
3. use `set_index`:

   Turn all columns you want to preserve into row index, after some complicated `apply` function and then `reset_index` to get columns back:

   ```
   df_tmp3 = df.set_index('TextID')

   df_tmp3 = df_tmp3.apply(
       lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x[0], orient='index').stack(), axis=1)

   df_tmp3 = df_tmp3.reset_index(level=0)
   print(df_tmp3)
   ```

   output:

   ```
       TextID Crisis_Level Special_Date Type     
                           0            0    0    1
   0  0038f0569e            c            a    d  NaN
   1  003eb6998d            d            a    a    d
   2  006da49ea0            d            a    a  NaN
   ```

   Check the type of columns

   ```
   df_tmp3.columns
   ```

   output:

   ```
   MultiIndex(levels=[['Crisis_Level', 'Special_Date', 'Type', 'TextID'], [0, 1, '']],
           codes=[[3, 0, 1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
   ```

So, If your `apply` function will return `MultiIndex` columns, and you want to preserve it, you may want to try the third method.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question specifies that the function should be applied to a Series, most of the answers seem to be applying the function to a DataFrame, with the function getting the relevant column from each row. This seems somewhat inelegant and potentially slow.

Say the function `f` takes a value in column `df["argument"]` and returns two values. The nicest way I've found to do it by applying to the column Series is this:

```
df[["value_1", "value_2"]] = df["argument"].apply(f).to_list()
```

Unlike `DataFrame.apply`, unfortunately `Series.apply` has no `result_type` parameter to expand the result into a DataFrame to assign to. But pandas understands just as well if you assign to a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this, for me it was also necessary in some cases to use the `unstack()` method, because otherwise I'd just get a new column that contained a dictionary.

It works like this:

```
df.groupby('variable')['value'].apply(lambda grp: {
    'Min': grp.min(),
    'Median': grp.median(),
    'Max': grp.max()
}).unstack()
```