# Function take values from a dataframe as parameter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which calculates the Holidays for a given year like this:

```
holidays = bf.Holidays(year)
```

the problem is, there is no way to edit the Holidays function so i need another solutions.

I have a datafame  with some years, example:

```
  year
0 2005
1 2011
2 2015
3 2017
```

right now if i do this:

```
yearX = year.get_value(0, 0)
```

and run

```
holidays = bf.Holidays(yearX)
```

it just calculates the holidays for the first year in the dataframe (2005)

How can i implement that the function should take every year and append it?

using a for loop?

Example how it works now:

```
    year = df['YEAR']
    yearX = year.get_value(0,0)
    holidays = bf.Holidays(year)
    holidays = holidays.get_holiday_list()
    print(holidays)
```

output:

```
DATE                                 
2005-01-01
2005-03-25
2005-03-27
2005-03-28
2005-05-01
```

but i want it to calculate for very dataframe row, not only the first one

Comment: Yes, a for loop might help but it is difficult to help without knowing what your function is doing.  Can you post more detail (i.e. the function and a minimal example)?

Comment: @tnknepp i added an example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
holidays = df.apply(bf.Holidays, axis=1)
```

It will apply function `bf.Holidays` to each row in your `df` DataFrame.

---

For the `df` from your question:

```
In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
   year
0  2010
1  2011
2  2015
3  2017

In [51]: def test(x):
    ...:     return x % 13
    ...: 

In [52]: df.apply(test, axis=1)
Out[52]: 
   year
0     8
1     9
2     0
3     2
```

Comment: bf.Holidays need a year as parameter, how should that work?

Comment: @Henrij because `.apply` passes it the parameter. Consider `def apply(f, val): return f(val)`, but `df.apply` works on data-frames, column-wise or row-wise

Comment: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Comment: @Henrij, try it on the example from your question.

Comment: 'year = df['YEAR']
year = year.drop_duplicates()
holidays = df.apply(bf.Holidays(), axis=1)
print(holidays)'   does not work

Comment: Ahh, sorry. the problem is : bf.Holidays takes a year as int and a state_code as second parameter. i thought thats not important for this case to mention it. But its like: bf.Holidays(year,'HH')

Comment: @Henrij, you can pass kwargs like: `df.year.apply(bf.Holidays, state_code='HH')`.

Comment: yes i did the following  `holidays = year.apply(bf.Holidays(), axis=1,state_code='HH') ` but the result is: `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'year' and 'state_code'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157069/discussion-between-henrij-and-randomir).

Comment: @Henrij, don't call `bf.Holidays()`, just pass the function `bf.Holidays` to `apply`.

Comment: i did. error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`

Comment: @Henrij, can you please just run the line from my previous comment: `df.year.apply(bf.Holidays, state_code='HH')`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586510/return-multiple-columns-from-apply-pandas) and just write a little wrapper function to return the dates to their respective columns:

```
def holiday_mapper(row):
    holidays = bf.Holidays(row['year'],'HH').get_holiday_list()
    row['holiday1'], row['holiday2']...row['holidayN'] = holidays
    return row

df = df.apply(holiday_mapper, axis=1)
```

Assuming your `get_holiday_list()` function actually returns a list, and that you want to store the holiday dates in columns for each holiday, rather than append a single column with all the dates.