# Pandas : Apply function that returns multiple rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `routes` with the following structure :

```
      id                                             nodes                            traveltimes
0   id-1                                  [node-A, node-B]                                  [6.0]
1   id-2                  [node-A, node-C, node-D, node-E]                      [4.0, 80.0, 38.0]
2   id-3                                  [node-B, node-D]                                 [90.0]
3   id-4                                          [node-A]                                     []
4   id-5  [node-A, node-B, node-C, node-D, node-E, node-D]         [35.0, 30.0, 110.0, 20.0, 5.0]
..                                                 ...                                    ...
```

The list of value in the `nodes` columns are the nodes of a graph, and the value in the `traveltimes` column are the time between two nodes. Each row corresponding to a `route` in the graph.

I want to split my `routes` on a threshold value of `traveltimes`. For example, for a threshold of 70, I want to get the following result :

```
      id     route_id                            nodes                            traveltimes
0     id-1          0                 [node-A, node-B]                                  [6.0]
1     id-2          0                 [node-A, node-C]                                  [4.0]        
2     id-2          1                 [node-D, node-E]                                 [38.0]
3     id-3          0                         [node-B]                                     []
4     id-3          1                         [node-D]                                     []
5     id-4          0                         [node-A]                                     []
6     id-5          0         [node-A, node-B, node-C]                           [35.0, 30.0]
7     id-5          1         [node-D, node-E, node-D]                            [20.0, 5.0]
..                                                 ...                                    ...
```

I made the following code that do what I want, but in an inefficient way.

I have a function that split the routes:

```
def split_routes(row):
    newrow = row.copy()

    threshold = 70

    nodes = newrow['nodes']
    traveltimes = newrow['traveltimes']

    rows = []
    route_id = 0
    route_nodes = []
    route_traveltimes = []

    route_nodes.append(nodes[0])

    for i in range(1, len(nodes)):
        if(traveltimes[i-1]<threshold):
            route_traveltimes.append(traveltimes[i-1])
            route_nodes.append(nodes[i])
        else : 
            # Route route_id completed, starting a new one
            newrow['route_id'] = route_id
            newrow['nodes'] = route_nodes
            newrow['traveltimes'] = route_traveltimes
            rows.append(newrow)

            newrow = row.copy()
            route_nodes = []
            route_traveltimes = []
            route_id+=1
            route_nodes.append(nodes[i])

    # Route route_id completed     
    newrow['route_id'] = route_id
    newrow['nodes'] = route_nodes
    newrow['traveltimes'] = route_traveltimes
    rows.append(newrow)

    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    return df
```

And this is how I use it :

```
splitted_routes_array = []

for index, row in routes.iterrows():    # Inefficient loop
    splitted_routes_array.append(split_routes(row))

splitted_routes = pd.concat(splitted_routes_array).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I guess I can do something way more efficient without iterating on rows by myself. But I couldn't figure out how to use `apply` to return multiple rows and columns at the same time.

Can someone give me some hints on that ?

Comment: This could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208597/1491350

Comment: I guess it is close to the solution of my problem. But when I use this I get a weird result. `splitted_routes = routes.apply(split_routes,axis=1)` give me a serie as output, where each element seems to contain a dataframe.

Comment: You can try using stack() and reset_index() as suggested in answer.

Answer (score 0):

To explode multiple columns in pandas the only prerequisite is having same number of elements in list in all columns to be exploded. This could be done by -

```
def get_nodes(x):
    if(len(x)<2):
        return []
    return [[x[i], x[i+1]] for i in range(len(x)-1)]

df['nodes'] = df['nodes'].apply(lambda x: get_nodes(x))
```

After this the data can be flattened using -

```
df = df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack()).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'route_id'})
```

To find all the routes having traveltimes greater than 70.0, we could simply do -

```
df[df['traveltimes']>70]
```