# Pandas AssertionError when applying function which returns tuple containing list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am applying a function to a Pandas `DataFrame`, and returning a `tuple`, to cast into multiple `DataFrame` columns using `zip(* )`.

The returned `tuple`, contains a `list`, containing one or more `tuples`.

In cases where at least one of the the nested `lists` contain a different count of `tuples` from the rest of the `lists`, everything works fine.

In rare cases where the function returns all nested `lists` with *equal* `tuple` counts within, an `AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape` is raised.

I suspect Pandas is seeing the consistent nested `list` lengths and is trying to unpack the `list(tuples)` into separate columns.

How can I force Pandas to always store the returned `list` as is, regardless of the conditions above?

---

*(Python 3.7.4, Pandas 1.0.3)*

Code that works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def simple_function(type_count):
    calculated_value1 = np.random.randint(5)
    calculated_value2 = np.random.randint(5)
    types_list = [tuple((x, calculated_value2)) for x in range(0, type_count)]
    return calculated_value1, types_list
    
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Joe', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'Beth', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'John', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'Jill', 'types': 2},
                   ], columns=['name', 'types'])

df['calculated_result'], df['types_list'] = zip(*df['types'].apply(simple_function))
```

Code that raises `AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def simple_function(type_count):
    calculated_value1 = np.random.randint(5)
    calculated_value2 = np.random.randint(5)
    types_list = [tuple((x, calculated_value2)) for x in range(0, type_count)]
    return calculated_value1, types_list
    
df = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'Joe', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'Beth', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'John', 'types': 1},
                   {'name': 'Jill', 'types': 1},
                   ], columns=['name', 'types'])

df['calculated_result'], df['types_list'] = zip(*df['types'].apply(simple_function))
```

Comment: you can try `df[['calculated_result','types_list']] = pd.DataFrame(df['types'].apply(simple_function).tolist())` as a work around but it might exist a better solution

Comment: The reason I used zip is for its [performance advantages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61039138/7696708). ```%timeit``` of ```zip(* )``` on ```simple_function``` yields ```553 µs ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)``` whereas your proposed solution is twice as slow with ```986 µs ± 8.99 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)```

That said, I'm grateful this solved my problem and I can return to work. If you post this as an answer, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: It was a nice answer you did :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a DataFrame from the list on your result:

```
df[['calculated_result','types_list']] = pd.DataFrame(df['types'].apply(simple_function).tolist())
```

You can get similar result with array

```
df['calculated_result'], df['types_list'] = np.array(df['types'].apply(simple_function).tolist()).T
```