# how to create multiple columns at once with apply?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'var2' : ['a','b','c','d']})
df
Out[100]: 
   var1 var2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    d
```

I have a function that takes `var1` as input and returns three values that I want to store into three different variables. The following seems to work correctly

```
    def myfunc(var):
        return [['small list'], var + 2, ['another list']]
    
    df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
    Out[101]: 
    0    [[small list], 3, [another list]]
    1    [[small list], 4, [another list]]
    2    [[small list], 5, [another list]]
    3    [[small list], 6, [another list]]
    Name: var1, dtype: object
```

However, when I try to create the corresponding variables I get an error

```
df[['my small list', 'my numeric', 'other list']]  = df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

What do you think?

I used to use the great `zip` solution in [Return multiple columns from pandas apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586510/return-multiple-columns-from-pandas-apply) but with the current Pandas `1.2` this solution does not work anymore

Thanks!

Comment: You could try and apply the answer from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns

Comment: By the way, you don't need to create a lambda function if you already have that function, you could do `df.var1.apply(myfunc)`

Comment: the issue is that the dataframe contains other columns as well that I need to keep. this solution does not seem optimal here

Comment: I'll write out the answer (you can keep the other columns as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning a series is possible the most readable solution.

```
def myfunc(var):
    return pd.Series([['small list'], var + 2, ['another list']])

df[['my small list', 'my numeric', 'other list']]  = df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

However, for larger dataframes you should prefer either the zip or the dataframe approach.

```
import pandas as pd # 1.2.2
import perfplot

def setup(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(
        var1=list(range(n))
    ))
 
def with_series(df):
    def myfunc(var):
        return pd.Series([['small list'], var + 2, ['other list']])
    out = pd.DataFrame()
    out[['small list', 'numeric', 'other list']] = df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))

def with_zip(df):
    def myfunc(var):
        return [['small list'], var + 2, ['other list']]
    out = pd.DataFrame()
    out['small list'], out['numeric'], out['other list'] = list(zip(*df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))))

def with_dataframe(df):
    def myfunc(var):
        return [['small list'], var + 2, ['other list']]
    out = pd.DataFrame()
    out[['small list', 'numeric', 'other list']] = pd.DataFrame(df.var1.apply(myfunc).to_list())


perfplot.show(
    setup=setup,
    kernels=[
        with_series,
        with_zip,
        with_dataframe,
    ],
    labels=["series", "zip", "df"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    xlabel="len(df)",
    equality_check=None,
)
```

[image]

Comment: this is a good one I think. I wonder about the performance though

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ added a performance comparison of the different approaches

Answer (score 3):

The zip method seems to work fine still:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1' : [1,2,3,4],
                   'var2' : ['a','b','c','d']})

def myfunc(var):
    return [['small list'], var + 2, ['another list']]

df['my small list'], df['my numeric'], df['other list'] = zip(*df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x)))
```

[image: notebook]

[Return multiple columns from pandas apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586510/return-multiple-columns-from-pandas-apply)

The really odd thing is how the inner lists are being coerced into tuples. From experimenting it seems to matter that the outer type is of type `list`.

To force the inner lists to stay lists I had to do the following:

```
df['my small list'], df['my numeric'], df['other list'] = (list(row) for row in zip(*df.var1.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))))
```

Comment: strange. I have pandas `1.2.0`

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Did you remember the asterisk in zip? What is the error message? I'm using 1.2.1, I'd expect it to fail like yours.

Comment: yes, that used to work with the *.... very strange. just a note, it seems the lists are actually tuples in your print?

Comment: Yeah. That is really odd? I updated the answer with more details. Turns out it depends on the type of the outer column collections.

Answer (score 2):

Using method from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns), you just need to split the pandas Series object coming from `df.var1.apply(myfunc)` into columns.

What I did was:

`df[['out1','out2','out3']] = pd.DataFrame(df['var1'].apply(myfunc).to_list())`

As you can see, this doesn't overwrite your DataFrame, just assigns the resulting columns to new columns in your DataFrame.

DataFrame after the apply method:

```
   var1 var2          out1  out2            out3
0     1    a  [small_list]     3  [another_list]
1     2    b  [small_list]     4  [another_list]
2     3    c  [small_list]     5  [another_list]
3     4    d  [small_list]     6  [another_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result_type` argument of [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```py
df[['my small list', 'my numeric', 'other list']]  = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x.var1), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

```
# print(df)

   var1 var2 my small list  my numeric      other list
0     1    a  [small list]           3  [another list]
1     2    b  [small list]           4  [another list]
2     3    c  [small list]           5  [another list]
3     4    d  [small list]           6  [another list]
```