# Dataframe Apply method to return multiple elements (series)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
```

Let's say I have a `dataframe` like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":range(4),"b":range(1,5)})
```

it looks like this:

```
   a  b
0  0  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  3  4
```

and a function that multiplies X by Y:

```
def XtimesY(x,y):
    return x*y
```

If I want to add a new pandas series to df I can do:

```
df["c"] =df.apply( lambda x:XtimesY(x["a"],2), axis =1)
```

It works !

Now I want to add multiple series:

I have this function:

```
def divideAndMultiply(x,y):
    return x/y, x*y
```

something like this ?:

```
df["e"], df["f"] = df.apply( lambda x: divideAndMultiply(x["a"],2) , axis =1)
```

It doesn't work !

I want the `'e'` column to receive the divisions and `'f'` column the multiplications !

Note: This is not the code I'm using but I'm expecting the same behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> Updated for version 0.23 - using `result_type='broadcast'` for further details refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Redefine your function like this:

```
def divideAndMultiply(x,y):
    return [x/y, x*y]
```

Then do this:

```
df[['e','f']] = df.apply(lambda x: divideAndMultiply(x["a"], 2), axis=1, result_type='broadcast')
```

You shall get the desired result:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]:
   a  b  e  f
0  0  1  0  0
1  1  2  0  2
2  2  3  1  4
3  3  4  1  6
```

Comment: I've seen this answer multiple times, but any time I've tried, I get `KeyError: "['e', 'f'] not in index`. I think pandas must have changed, does it still work for you @Abbas?

Comment: It still works. Follow the question and answer to reproduce the results.

Comment: https://repl.it/@seaders/SuperbIncompatibleAudacity it doesn't, not on Python 3.6 and pandas 0.23.1 - `KeyError`.

Comment: @seaders you are right, this answer doesn't work in 0.23.1 & this answer works https://stackoverflow.com/a/36600318/1437877

Comment: Good stuff @Abbas, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy. I can't find anywhere in the docs that this *was* the correct way of doing things, to then be able to see they've changed it, so it's all pretty unclear!

Comment: @seaders I've updated the answer with keyword result_type='broadcast' and now it shall work without `zip`.

Answer (score 21):

Almost there. Use zip* to unpack the function. Try this:

```
def divideAndMultiply(x,y):
    return x/y, x*y

df["e"], df["f"] = zip(*df.a.apply(lambda val: divideAndMultiply(val,2)))
```

Comment: Most elegant solution to this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df["e"], df["f"] = zip(*df.apply( lambda x: divideAndMultiply(x["a"],2) , axis =1))
```

Should do the trick.

(I show this example so you can see how to use multiple columns as the input to create multiple new columns)

Answer (score 0):

the following solution to this frustratingly frustrating question works for me. I found the original suggestion in another StackOverflow post a while ago. The trick is to wrap up the return values into a Series like this:

```
def divideAndMultiply(x,y):
    return pd.Series([x/y, x*y])
```

Then this works as you wanted:

```
df[['e','f']] = df.apply( lambda x: divideAndMultiply(x["a"],2) , axis =1)
```