# Pandas applying function on multiple columns with multiple inputs does not work with column datetime

Tags: python, pandas

based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734131/applying-function-on-multiple-columns-to-create-multiple-new-columns) I have a follow-up question.

ManelFornos Code does exactly what I need:

```
import quandl
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd

mysql_cn= MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,user='px_user', passwd='ProjectX2016', db='px')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

columns = ["High", 'Low', 'Close']


def operations(row, columns):
    df1 = row[columns[0]] + row[columns[1]] + row[columns[2]]
    df2 = -row[columns[1]] - row[columns[2]] + row[columns[0]]
    return df1, df2

print(df.info())
df["function1"], df["function2"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: operations(row, columns), axis=1))

print(df.info())
print(df[["High","Low","Close","function1", "function2"]].head(5))
```

but in my dataframe, I have a DateTime Column, which results in an error:

```
import quandl
import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd

mysql_cn= MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,user='px_user', passwd='ProjectX2016', db='px')

df = quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")

columns = ["High", 'Low', 'Close']


df['DateTime'] = df.index

def operations(row, columns):
    df1 = row[columns[0]] + row[columns[1]] + row[columns[2]]
    df2 = -row[columns[1]] - row[columns[2]] + row[columns[0]]
    return df1, df2

print(df.info())
df["function1"], df["function2"] = zip(*df.apply(lambda row: operations(row, columns), axis=1))

print(df.info())
print(df[["High","Low","Close","function1", "function2"]].head(5)
```

this error is thrown:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3211, 2), indices imply (3211, 13)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks!
e.

Comment: Wow, that's a weird one... what happens when you do `df["function1"], df["function2"] = zip(*df.drop('DateTime', axis=1).apply(lambda row: operations(row, columns), axis=1))`?

Comment: @BobHaffner yeah. that solves my issue!!! thanks!