# Splitting multiple/all columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe full of tuple (it could be the same with arrays) and I would like to split all the  columns into even more columns (each array or tuple has the same length).
Let's take this as an example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]], df.columns=['column0', 'column1'])
```

which outputs:

```
    column0 column1  
0   (1, 2)   (3, 4)  
1   (5, 6)   (7, 8)
```

I tried to build over this solution here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245109/4218755) using derivates off the expression:

```
df.textcol.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s+1, 'feature2':s-1})
```

like

```
df.column0.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s[0], 'feature2':s[1]})
```

which outputs:

```
       feature1  feature2  
 0         1         2   
 1         5         6
```

This is the desired behavior. So it works well, but if I happen to try to use

```
 df2=df[df.columns].apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s[0], 'feature2':s[1]}))
```

then df2 is:

```
         colonne0 colonne1
 feature1   (1, 2)   (3, 4)   
 feature2   (5, 6)   (7, 8)
```

which is obviously wrong. I can't either apply on df, it output the same result as df2.

How to apply such splitting technique to a whole dataframe, and are there alternatives?
Thanks

Comment: I am approaching the solution with :     df2=df.applymap(lambda s: pd.Series({'feat1':s[0],'feat2': s[1]})). It outputs ;                             colonne0                            colonne1
0  feat1    1
feat2    2
dtype: int64  feat1    3
feat2    4
dtype: int64
1  feat1    5
feat2    6
dtype: int64  feat1    7
feat2    8
dtype: int64 but I am stuck with this index (and df2.reset_index is not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the DataFrame values as a NumPy array, use `IT.chain.from_iterable` to extract the ints from the tuples, and then reshape and rebuild the array into a new DataFrame:

```
import itertools as IT
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]], columns=['column0', 'column1'])
arr = df.values
arr = np.array(list(IT.chain.from_iterable(arr))).reshape(len(df), -1)
result = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

yields

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
```

---

By the way, you might have fallen into an XY-trap -- you're asking for `X` when
you really should be looking for `Y`. Instead of trying to transform `df` into
`result`, it might be easier to build the *desired DataFrame*, `result`, from
the original data source.

For example, if your original data is a list of lists of tuples:

```
data = [[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]]
```

Then the desired DataFrame could be built using

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data).reshape(2,-1))
#    0  1  2  3
# 0  1  2  3  4
# 1  5  6  7  8
```

Once you have non-NumPy-native data types in your DataFrame
(such as tuples), you are doomed to using at least one Python loop to extract
the ints from the tuples. (I'm regarding things like `df.apply(func)` and
`list(IT.chain.from_iterable(arr))` as essentially Python loops since they work
at Python-loop speed.)

Comment: Thanks for your help! actually I believed that applymap and apply performed some kind of vectorized operations, that's why I preferred to start from the tuples df instead of reusing the original df from which it was made from (which was pretty simple to convert). Finally I had myself used something along the line of making 2 copies, then using splitframe1.applymap(lambda x: x[0]) and     splitframe2.applymap(lambda x: x[1]) and merging after renaming columns. In any case, your solution and additional infos are worth acception your answer as the best.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]], columns=['column0', 'column1'])
print (df)
  column0 column1
0  (1, 2)  (3, 4)
1  (5, 6)  (7, 8)


for col in df.columns: 
    df[col]=df[col].apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'feature1':s[0], 'feature2':s[1]}))

print (df)
   column0  column1
0        1        3
1        5        7
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Actually  I would expect to have 2,6 in a second column and 4,8 in a fourth, too. I don't understand why your code doesn't output this, I expected this by reading it. I did not precised it either, but I would like to avoid loops if possible (I take the idea as valuable, thought, if no alternative is available).

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate over each column you want to split and assign the new columns to your DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame( [ [ (1,2), (3,4)],
                   [ (5,6), (7,8)] ], columns=['column0', 'column1'])

# empty DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df.columns:
    # names of new columns
    feature_columns  = [ "{col}_feature1".format(col=col), "{col}_feature2".format(col=col) ]
    # split current column
    df2[ feature_columns ] = df[ col ].apply(lambda s: pd.Series({ feature_columns[0]: s[0],
                                                                   feature_columns[1]: s[1]} ) )

print df2
```

which gives

```
  column0_feature1  column0_feature2  column1_feature1  column2_feature2
0                1                 2                 3                 4 
1                5                 6                 7                 8
```

Comment: Very clever, thanks. It won't be the accepted answer because the itertools one looks better at avoiding loops, but it seems valuable.