# Apply function to all columns and add new columns with new names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I do have a dataframe `df` with several columns like this:

```
       col1      col2
0  0.627521  0.026832
1  0.470450  0.319736
2  0.015760  0.484664
3  0.645810  0.733688
4  0.850554  0.506945
```

I want to apply a function to each of these columns and add the results as additional columns (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)) whereby the names are the original names plus a common suffix for all added columns.

I tried the following (highly simplified case):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def do_and_rename(s, s2):

    news = s + s2
    news.name = s.name + "_change"

    return news

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.rand(5), 'col2': np.random.rand(5)})

new_df = pd.concat([df, df.apply(lambda x: do_and_rename(x, df.index))], axis=1)
```

which gives me

```
       col1      col2      col1      col2
0  0.627521  0.026832  0.627521  0.026832
1  0.470450  0.319736  1.470450  1.319736
2  0.015760  0.484664  2.015760  2.484664
3  0.645810  0.733688  3.645810  3.733688
4  0.850554  0.506945  4.850554  4.506945
```

The calculations are correct but the column names are wrong.

My desired output would be

```
       col1      col2  col1_change  col2_change
0  0.627521  0.026832  0.627521  0.026832
1  0.470450  0.319736  1.470450  1.319736
2  0.015760  0.484664  2.015760  2.484664
3  0.645810  0.733688  3.645810  3.733688
4  0.850554  0.506945  4.850554  4.506945
```

If I just do

```
do_and_rename(df['col1'], df.index)
```

I get

```
0    0.627521
1    1.470450
2    2.015760
3    3.645810
4    4.850554
Name: col1_change, dtype: float64
```

with the correct name. How can I use these returned names as columns headers?

Comment: @Zero: Sure, added it.

Comment: Ideally, why not use `df.join(df.add(df.index.values, axis=0).add_suffix('_change'))`?

Comment: @Zero: that's always the issue with minimal examples. In my actual case I don't want to do just an addition but apply a more complicated function.

Comment: Feel free to add it as solution; will be happy to upvote it if it works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df] + [do_and_rename(df[x], df.index) for x in df], axis=1)
print (new_df)
       col1      col2  col1_change  col2_change
0  0.364028  0.694481     0.364028     0.694481
1  0.457195  0.813740     1.457195     1.813740
2  0.286694  0.133999     2.286694     2.133999
3  0.130283  0.398216     3.130283     3.398216
4  0.694586  0.936815     4.694586     4.936815
```

Comment: really nice with concat

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make a new DataFrame, you can just do this:

```
for col in df:
    df[col + '_change'] = df[col] + df.index
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `df.join(your_func(df, args ...,).add_suffix('_change'))` pattern. Where, `your_func` returns your modified `dataframe`

```
In [1459]: def your_func(df, s):
      ...:     dff = df.add(s, axis=0)
      ...:     return dff
      ...:

In [1460]: df.join(your_func(df, df.index.values).add_suffix('_change'))
Out[1460]:
       col1      col2  col1_change  col2_change
0  0.627521  0.026832     0.627521     0.026832
1  0.470450  0.319736     1.470450     1.319736
2  0.015760  0.484664     2.015760     2.484664
3  0.645810  0.733688     3.645810     3.733688
4  0.850554  0.506945     4.850554     4.506945

In [1461]: df
Out[1461]:
       col1      col2
0  0.627521  0.026832
1  0.470450  0.319736
2  0.015760  0.484664
3  0.645810  0.733688
4  0.850554  0.506945
```