# Pandas apply a function that return a list to more column

Tags: python, pandas

I've a function that perform a modification  on a string, under some condition  than return a list containing modified string and a boolean check if new string is obtained.
I want apply func to pandas dataframe column and store result in two new created columns. I found an inelegant way to achieve this purpose:

The main method is:

```
def alter_string(astring):
  ...
  return altered_string, boolean_check

def _perform_mod(astring):
  return alter_string(astring)[0]

def _check():
  return alter_string(astring)[1]

df['modified']=df['original'].apply(_perform_mod)
df['check']=df['original'].apply(_check)
```

In this way I achieve my goal but I have to run twice an heavy computational method. I wonder if there is a better way

Add some details to clarify my question
I've a dataframe column `'original_string'` containing string that are molecular descriptors, I apply to this string a function that can modify or not the string under some circumstances. The function return modified string and True or same string and False. I need to add two new columns to dataframe, `modified_string` and `check` Here a short sample

```
original --->  modified check

AAAAAA ----->  AAAAAA False
AAABCD ----->  AAAVCD True
ACCBDE ----->  AACADE True
```

`

Comment: please provide us with some sample data and then your expected output so we can provide any alternatives, right now we dont know what exactly your code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['modified'], df['check'] =  zip(*df['original'].apply(alter_string))
```

This way you run `alter_string` function only once.

`zip` function creates a list of tuples, where each tuple is a series.
Then through tuple unpacking (`df['modified'], df['check']`) we create our brand new columns in dataframe.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27385043/5299969)

Comment: thank you is exactly what I was looking for. Work flawless.  I know zip function. Can you explain  * operator ahead column name? Is it pandas related?

Comment: @MicheleMontaruli "*" is purely a Python core functionality, it is used here to unpack arguments for the zip function. [you can read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/5299969). As an example, here it is used to give to zip every result tuple from apply (for example tuples "(AAAAAA, False)" and "(AAAVCD,True)" ) as a different argument. So if the result from apply are tuples "(AAAAAA, False)" and "(AAAVCD,True)", with "*" you basically call zip like this: `zip((AAAAAA, False), (AAAVCD,True))`. Better to play around with this functionality to fully grasp it though)