# Removing duplictes appearing in two or more columns Python

Tags: python, duplicates, subset

Same problem but it didn't help. [How To Solve KeyError: u"None of [Index([..], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652574/how-to-solve-keyerror-unone-of-index-dtype-object-are-in-the-colum)
First try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ABCD.csv', index_col=['A'])
df=df.drop_duplicates(['A'],['B'])
```

*KeyError: Index(['Sample_ID'], dtype='object')*

Here I have found out that it impossible to removed the index itself so I removed it from the top:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ABCD.csv')
df=df.drop_duplicates(['A'],['B'],keep = 'first')
```

*TypeError: drop_duplicates() got multiple values for argument 'keep'*

When I print df(type) it posts "DataFrame" , what could be the problem?

Comment: remove `]` and you can use `inplace=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that would be

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'],keep = 'first')
```

instead of:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(['A'],['B'],keep = 'first')
```

The subset must be a list of columns, not separate to multiple arguments:
**subsetcolumn label or sequence of labels, optional** [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

PS: You should use `df.drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], keep='first', inplace=True)`, you dont need to assign back to `df` when adding `inplace`

Comment: Thank you, that was embarrassing, I used the" inplace Ttrue" now instead either.