# Getting error None of the type in columns in pandas, python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to train a machine learning model on a dataset using KFold. I keep getting this key error and don't know how to solve it. 
I have tried methods mentioned in
[How To Solve KeyError: u"None of [Index([..], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652574/how-to-solve-keyerror-unone-of-index-dtype-object-are-in-the-colum)
This is my code

```
diffFile = pd.read_csv('Difference.csv', delimiter=',', delim_whitespace= 0)
X = diffFile.iloc[:,[0,1,2]]
y = diffFile.iloc[:,3]
adb = AdaBoostClassifier()
scores = []
kf = KFold(n_splits=30)
for train_index,test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train,X_test=X[train_index],X[test_index]
    y_train,y_test=y[train_index],y[test_index]
    adb.fit(X_train,y_train)
    scores.append(adb.score(X_test,y_test))
```

And this is my file
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VwBNSADq6l893VFiULVPzrBYiB-fqyo/view?usp=sharing

I am using Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.7
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
X_train,X_test=X.iloc[train_index],X.iloc[test_index]
y_train,y_test=y.iloc[train_index],y.iloc[test_index]
```

you are trying to index the X using X[train_index] but you have pandas dataframe here.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am a beginner in Data Science, can you recommend any course for me?

Comment: paid : appliedaicourse,
free: there are some youtube channel like krish naik's channel