# KeyError when trying to '.pop()' a column from data

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# path of the training data
train_data_path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Machine_Learning/Neural_Network/addition_train_data.csv"
train_data = pd.read_csv(train_data_path)  # loads the data using pandas

# sets a target variable for the ML to predict
# train_target = train_data.pop("Sum")

# path of the evalution data
eval_data_path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Machine_Learning/Neural_Network/addition_eval_data.csv"
# loads the data using pandas (again)
eval_data = pd.read_csv(eval_data_path)

# sets a target variable, same as the train_target
eval_target = eval_data.pop("Factor_2")
```

And here are my errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc                                                                                                                                            
return self._engine.get_loc(key)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc                                                                                                                                                           
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc                                                                                                                                                           
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item                                                                                                                              
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item                                                                                                                            
KeyError: 'Factor_2'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                             
File "addition.py", line 27, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                                                       
eval_target = eval_data.pop("Factor_2")                                                                                                                                                                                                    
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 790, in pop                                                                                                                                                      
result = self[item]                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__                                                                                                                                               
indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)                                                                                                                                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc                                                                                                                                            
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))                                                                                                                                                                                 
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc                                                                                                                                                           
File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc                                                                                                                                                           
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1618, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item                                                                                                                              
File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1626, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item                                                                                                                            
KeyError: 'Factor_2'
```

I was trying to load two files, but when I tried to pop the target variable, it return a KeyError. I did some research on it, but it's a broad error.

Here are my data files:

Training:

```
Factor_1, Factor_2, Sum
0, 0, 0
1, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
1, 1, 2
2, 0, 2
0, 2, 2
2, 1, 3
1, 2, 3
3, 0, 3
0, 3, 0
3, 1, 4
1, 3, 4
3, 2, 5
2, 3, 5
3, 3, 6
0, 4, 4
4, 0, 4
4, 1, 5
1, 4, 5
4, 2, 6
2, 4, 6
4, 3, 7
3, 4, 7
4, 4, 8
5, 0, 5
0, 5, 5
5, 1, 6
1, 5, 6
5, 2, 7
2, 5, 7
5, 3, 8
3, 5, 8
5, 4, 9
4, 5, 9
5, 5, 10
```

Evaluation:

```
Factor_1, Factor_2, Sum
10, 0,
0, 10,
10, 1,
1, 10,
10, 2,
2, 10,
10, 3,
3, 10,
10, 4,
4, 10,
10, 5,
5, 10,
10, 6,
6, 10
10, 7,
7, 10,
10, 8,
8, 10,
10, 9,
9, 10,
10, 10,
20, 20
```

For the evaluation data, the 'Sum' column is empty--it's for the ML to predict.

I am still pretty new to Tensorflow and ML, any help, tips, and advice are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a standard `pandas` question, and it has nothing to do with `tensorflow` or `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the name. The error message is clearly stating that 'Factor_2' is not valid. So you need to figure out what the actual column name is.

Use df.columns to get the column names.

Check for leading and trailing spaces. Is the comma part of the name?

Alternatively you could rename the columns.

```
eval_data.columns = ["Factor_1", "Factor_2", "Sum"]
```

Then you should be able to pop your column.

Comment: Apparently, there, whitespace is included in the name. I have removed it. Now it works.

Comment: Nice catch; related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652574/how-to-solve-keyerror-unone-of-index-dtype-object-are-in-the-colum