# How do I efficiently loop over this dataframe and perform a function using inbuilt numpy or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I read [this](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-efficiently-loop-through-pandas-dataframe-660e4660125d?) article earlier and noticed that the pandas apply function, iterrows and for loop are terribly slow and efficient way of working with pandas dataframes.

I am doing sentiment analysis on some text data, but using apply causes high memory usage and low speeds similar to shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245109/9292995) answer.

```
%%time
data.merge(data.essay.apply(lambda s: pd.Series({'neg':sid.polarity_scores(s)['neg'],
                                                 'neu':sid.polarity_scores(s)['neu'],
                                                 'pos':sid.polarity_scores(s)['pos'],
                                                 'compound':sid.polarity_scores(s)['compound']})),
                       left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

How can I implement this using either built-in numpy or pandas function?
Edit:- The column contains essay text data

Comment: you could try [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter)

Comment: data.merge(data.essay.swifter.apply.
Like this?

Comment: Checked it, seems it performs even worse than pandas apply as swifter uses pandas apply in my case but also does sample applies, causing additional overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to perform this function faster by using [pandarallel](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandaral-lel-a-simple-and-efficient-tool-to-parallelize-your-pandas-operations-on-all-your-cpus-bb5ff2a409ae).

By using the default pandas apply function it took 9 min 24 secs,

But by using pandarallel it completed the operation in just 1 min 7 secs (Using 16 workers).