# Pandas apply with swifter on axis 1 doesn't return

Tags: python, pandas, swifter

I try to apply the following code (minimal example) to my 2 Million rows DataFrame, but for some reason .apply returns more than one row to the function and breaks my code. I'm not sure what changed, but the code did run before.

```
def function(row):

  return [row[clm1], row[clm2]]


res = pd.DataFrame()
res[["clm1", "clm2"]] = df.swifter.apply(function,axis=1)
```

Did anyone get an idea or a similar issue?

**Important** without swifter everything works fine, but too slow due to the amount of rows.

Answer (score 1):

This should work ==>

```
  def function(row_different_name):
        
        return [row_different_name[clm1], row_different_name[clm2]]
        
        
  res = pd.DataFrame()
  res[["clm1", "clm2"]] = df.swifter.apply(function,axis=1)
```

Try changing the name of function parameter rwo to some other name.

Answer (score 0):

based on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns) what you are trying to do should work if you change it like this:

```
def function(row):
  return [row.swifter[clm1], row.swifter[clm2]]


res = pd.DataFrame()
res[["clm1", "clm2"]] = df.apply(function, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

this because [apply on a column](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) lacks `result_type` as arg, while [apply on a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) has it

Comment: Tried this sadly didn't work. See my edit. The code runs as is without swifter.

Comment: sorry my mistake, I should have removed swifter from `df.swifter.apply` as I said :D

Comment: swifter is a library for multiprocess pandas apply

Comment: yes I didn't know that the problem only appeared with swifter though

Answer (score -1):

`axis=1` means column, so it will insert it vertically. Is that what you want? Try removing `axis=1`

Comment: I know what you mean, but this will return column by column for some reason.