# How to extract individual returns from map?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create columns for the geolocation of countries from a CSV.

So far I am able to create a new column with both `latitude` and `longitude` by mapping over the columns and applying the `geolocate()` function.

**Dataframe**

```
geolocation
(-34.9964963, -64.9672817)
```

**Expected output:**

```
geolocation                   latitude     longitude
(-34.9964963, -64.9672817)  -34.9964963    -64.9672817
```

I am mapping over the the columns so I am not sure how to get just the latitude and longitude and make their respective columns.

```
def add_geolocation(df, country_column):
  df["geolocation"] = country_column.map(lambda x: geolocate(x))
  return df


add_geolocation(df=df, country_column=df["country"])
```

In the function `geolocate()` I return both of them.

```
def geolocate(country):
  # Location
  loc = geolocator.geocode(country, timeout=10000)
  # Latitiude
  lat = get_latitude(loc)
  # Longitude
  long_ = get_longitude(loc)
  # Address 
  add = get_address(loc)
  return lat, long_
```

Would it be possible for me to specify in the lambda function that I want to just use the latitude.

For example, `latitude, longitude = geolocate(country)` then just use the values latitude.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Hi apologies for not wording it right. I am trying to get the ```lat``` and ```long``` while mapping over the columns using the lambda function ```country_column.map(lambda x: geolocate(x))```.

Comment: And what is the problem? Do you get any error? Does the expected output differ from the actual output?

Comment: Yes it works fine but it returns both of them together. I am trying to just get the latitude then make a column with it and the same for longitude.

Comment: `return lat, long_` - this is why it returns both. your code return both. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns gow to create multiple columns

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I am asking if I could specify in the lambda function that I want to just use the ```latitude```. For example, ```latitude, longitude = geolocate(country)``` then just use the values ```latitude```.

Comment: As a note, you don't need a lambda here at all. Just run country_column.map(geolocate)

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to unpack the tuple inside the `geolocation` column:

```
def add_geolocation(df, country_column):
    df["geolocation"] = country_column.map(geolocate)
    df['lat'], df['long'] = zip(*df['geolocation'])
    return df
```

---

**Edit**: what does `zip(*df['geolocation'])` do? This is a combination of two different concepts: the star (`*`) operator and the `zip` function.

The `*` operator unpacks the collection into positional arguments. The following two calls are equivalent:

```py
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

f(1, 2) # return 3

lst = [1,2]
f(*lst) # return 3
```

The `zip` function returns elements from the input collections pair-wise:

```py
zip([1,2], ['A', 'B'], ['One', 'Two']) # return (1, 'A', 'One'), (2, 'B', 'Two')
```

We combine the two here to split the first elements of the `geolocation` tuples into a separate collection, and the second elements into another collection:

```py
geolocation
(1,2)
(3,4)
(5,6)

zip(*df['geolocation']) == zip((1,2), (3,4), (5,6)) == [(1,3,5), (2,4,6)]
# The first is a collection of latitudes, second is longitudes
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but I am not sure what is the ```*df['geolocation']```? Could you explain that?

Answer (score 1):

You could this instead of using `map` and a lambda function:

```
df["latitude"] = df["geolocations"].str[0]
df["longitude"] = df["geolocations"].str[1]
```

And as Ben said in comment, even shorter:

```
df["latitude"], df["longitude"] = df["geolocations"].str
```

Comment: even shorter: `df["latitude"], df["longitude"] = df["geolocations"].str`