# How to remove a portion of text from a column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Quite new to Python so apologies if there is an obvious fix to this. I'm working with some football data and the player names have come out like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ffX.png]

To remove everything after the "\" I tried:

```
head, sep, tail = df2["Player"].partition("\\")
head = df2["Player"]
```

To which I'm getting the following error:

> "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'partition'"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try `df2["Player"] = df2["Player"].str.split('\\').str[0]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)

Comment: To add to @ShubhamSharma's comment, you need to use the str accessor `df.column.str` to do string operations

Comment: I tried @ShubhamSharma's suggestion but got this: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @Oso What do you mean? ShubhamSharma has included .str before the functions?

Comment: @SanthiCazorla I was just adding exposition to the line of code, the key is the `.str` after the field.

Comment: @mayosten Unfortunately not, do not quite understand the code written here

Comment: @Oso Please can you explain what you mean? Sorry very new to Python

Comment: @SanthiCazorla i guess in this case you can safely ignore the warning. To read more about `SettingWithCopyWarning` check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/12833166)

Comment: @SanthiCazorla if you want to use string functions on a pandas column, you specify that: `df.column.split()` won't work, but `df.column.str.split()` does because you're using the `str` accessor

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I will take a look at that, thank you! I realised it worked :)

Comment: @SanthiCazorla happy coding :)

Comment: @Oso Ok got you. Why do we need the ".str[0]" . Why can't it be: df2["Player"] = df2["Player"].str.split('\\')[0]?

Comment: FYI, this will only work if all the names are capitalized. For example, if you have `\t` or `\n` Python will read that as a special character and will not split on it just using `str.split('\\')`. But if your names are all caps, should work