# python pandas data frame: assign function return tuple to two columns of a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply, assign

I want to add two columns to a pandas `Dataframe` using a function that gives back a `tuple` as such:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':['ssdfsdf','bbbbbb','cccccccccccc','ddd','eeeeee','ffffff']})

def givetup(string):
    
    result1 = string[0:3]
    # please imagine here a bunch of string functions concatenated.
    # including nlp methods with SpaCy 
    result2 = result1.upper()
    # the same here, imagine a bunch of steps to calculate result2 based on result 1
    
    return (result1,result2)

data['c'] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: givetup(x)[0])
data['d'] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: givetup(x)[1])
```

This is very inefficient (I am dealing with millions of rows) since I call two times the same function and make two calculations.
Since `result2` depends on `result 1` I better not separate `givetup` into two functions
How can I assign in one go `result1` and `result2` into new columns **c** and **d** with only one call to the function?
what is the most efficient way to do it?

Please bear in mind that `result1` and `result2` are heavily time consuming string calculations.

EDIT 1:
I knew about this:
[Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)

i.e. applying vectorized functions. In my particular case it is highly undesirable or perhaps even impossible. Imagine that result 1 and result 2 are calculated based on language models and I need the plain text.

Comment: *result2 depends on result 1* is it possible to write two (vectorized)  functions, one to get `result1` and one to get `result2` separately. Then you can do `data['c'] = func1(data['b']); data['d'] = func2(data['c'])`?

Comment: To follow up on what @QuangHoang said.  I vectorized like this `data.assign(c=lambda d: d.b.str[0:3], d=lambda d: d.c.str.upper())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `zip`/`map`

```
data['c'], data['d'] = zip(*map(givetup, data['b']))

data

   a             b    c    d
0  1       ssdfsdf  ssd  SSD
1  2        bbbbbb  bbb  BBB
2  3  cccccccccccc  ccc  CCC
3  4           ddd  ddd  DDD
4  5        eeeeee  eee  EEE
5  6        ffffff  fff  FFF
```

---

#### `Series.str` and `assign`

This is specific to the examples given in `givetup`.  But if it is possible to disentangle, then it is likely worth it.

The `assign` method arguments can take calables that reference columns created in an argument jus prior (NEAT).

```
data.assign(c=lambda d: d.b.str[0:3], d=lambda d: d.c.str.upper())

   a             b    c    d
0  1       ssdfsdf  ssd  SSD
1  2        bbbbbb  bbb  BBB
2  3  cccccccccccc  ccc  CCC
3  4           ddd  ddd  DDD
4  5        eeeeee  eee  EEE
5  6        ffffff  fff  FFF
```

---

#### Timings

```
data = pd.concat([data] * 10_000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit data['c'], data['d'] = zip(*map(givetup, data['b']))
%timeit data[['c','d']] = [givetup(a) for a in data['b']]
%timeit data.assign(c=lambda d: d.b.str[0:3], d=lambda d: d.c.str.upper())

69.7 ms ± 865 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
137 ms ± 937 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
34.6 ms ± 235 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Seems like the second one is the way to go. The third one is not possible in myparticular case

Comment: the first and the second solutions here give: 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:102: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray. return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

what does it mean?

Comment: that means your tuples are not of length two and the toy example was not representative of your actual situation.

Comment: You can do this to ensure you always only get two, `data['c'], data['d'] = zip(*[x[:2] for x in map(givetup, data['b'])])`

Answer (score 2):

You can try list comprehension here:

```
data[['c','d']] = [givetup(a) for a in data['b']]
```

Output:

```
   a             b    c    d
0  1       ssdfsdf  ssd  SSD
1  2        bbbbbb  bbb  BBB
2  3  cccccccccccc  ccc  CCC
3  4           ddd  ddd  DDD
4  5        eeeeee  eee  EEE
5  6        ffffff  fff  FFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is use apply function with series:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':['ssdfsdf','bbbbbb','cccccccccccc','ddd','eeeeee','ffffff']})

def givetup(column):
    
    column1 = column[0:3]
    column2 = column[0:3].upper()
    
    return pd.Series([column1, column2])

data[['c','d']] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: givetup(x))
```

Comment: This approach is likely to be very inefficient.  First of all, you are creating a `pd.Series` for every row.  Then you are asking Pandas to align those new columns for every row.  Also, `column1 = column[0:3]` already slices the string.  You do it again when you `column2 = column[0:3].upper()`  that is wasteful to do every row.  The timings for this are on the order of 1000 times slower.