# Pandas create columns from dictionary-returning function applied to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

##### Problem

I have a function that takes as input a `str` and returns a `dict`. I would like to apply this function to a specific column of every row of a pandas dataframe, and have it create new columns with the returned dictionary

##### Function

```py
example = "TGGCCCGCGAACTTGCCCGAAGCCCTCGTTCCCTGTCGGCTCTAACCGCTGGTGTAGTGG[CG]GAGCACGCGAACTTAGCAAGGGCTAAGCGATCAGGAATAAGAACAGCAGGAAAGCCAGAG"

def freqcount(s):
    bases = "".join(s.split("[CG]"))
    total = len(bases)
    outdic = {}
    for b1 in ["A", "G", "C", "T"]:
        outdic[b1] = bases.count(b1)/total
        for b2 in ["A", "G", "C", "T"]:
            outdic[b1+b2] = bases.count(b1+b2)/total
    return outdic

print(freqcount(example))
```

```py
{'A': 0.25833333333333336, 'AA': 0.08333333333333333, 'AG': 0.10833333333333334, 'AC': 0.041666666666666664, 'AT': 0.016666666666666666, 'G': 0.30833333333333335, 'GA': 0.075, 'GG': 0.058333333333333334, 'GC': 0.10833333333333334, 'GT': 0.041666666666666664, 'C': 0.275, 'CA': 0.05, 'CG': 0.075, 'CC': 0.05, 'CT': 0.06666666666666667, 'T': 0.15833333333333333, 'TA': 0.041666666666666664, 'TG': 0.05, 'TC': 0.041666666666666664, 'TT': 0.025}
```

##### Dataframe

```py
print(df_dna)
```

```py
                                                  Forward_Sequence
cg00050873       TATCTCTGTCTGGCGAGGAGGCAACGCACAACTGTGGTGGTTTTTG...
cg00212031       CCATTGGCCCGCCCCAGTTGGCCGCAGGGACTGAGCAAGTTATGCG...
cg00213748       TCTGTGGGACCATTTTAACGCCTGGCACCGTTTTAACGATGGAGGT...
cg00214611       GCGCCGGCAGGACTAGCTTCCGGGCCGCGCTTTGTGTGCTGGGCTG...
cg00455876       CGCGTGTGCCTGGACTCTGAGCTACCCGGCACAAGCTCCAAGGGCT...
...                                                            ...
ch.22.909671F    TTTTCCTTTTAGCTGCTGATAGATTAATAGTATGTGAACCTTTTAA...
ch.22.46830341F  TGTGCATACATGCGCATGTGAACAGTCCATGGAGCTTAATCCCCTG...
ch.22.1008279F   CTGGCAGGGCACACACCTCAGCTGGGCCCTGTGGCAGGTGAACCCC...
ch.22.47579720R  ATGTACCCATACGGGAAAGGCCGCGTGAAGATGGAGACAGAGATGG...
ch.22.48274842R  AGTGTAGAATTTGGGGCTCGCCCTGTTGGTTCCTCCGGTGTGAAGG...

[485512 rows x 1 columns]
```

##### Expected output

I would like to have new columns, `A`, `AA`, `AG`, ..., and have the dictionary values in the correct column for each row.

##### Output i get so far

However this is what I get.

```py
print(df_dna.applymap(freqcount))
```

```py
                                             Forward_Sequence
cg00050873  {'A': 0.21666666666666667, 'AA': 0.04166666666...
cg00212031  {'A': 0.21666666666666667, 'AA': 0.04166666666...
cg00213748  {'A': 0.18333333333333332, 'AA': 0.01666666666...
cg00214611  {'A': 0.14166666666666666, 'AA': 0.025, 'AG': ...
cg00455876  {'A': 0.15, 'AA': 0.025, 'AG': 0.0833333333333...
cg01707559  {'A': 0.10833333333333334, 'AA': 0.01666666666...
cg02004872  {'A': 0.13333333333333333, 'AA': 0.0, 'AG': 0....
cg02011394  {'A': 0.175, 'AA': 0.016666666666666666, 'AG':...
cg02050847  {'A': 0.175, 'AA': 0.025, 'AG': 0.05, 'AC': 0....
cg02233190  {'A': 0.225, 'AA': 0.03333333333333333, 'AG': ...
```

I get same result with

```py
print(df_dna.apply(lambda row: freqcount(row["Forward_Sequence"]), axis=1))
```

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just found the answer, using the `result_type` argument:

```py
df_dna.apply(lambda row: freqcount(row["Forward_Sequence"]), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

```py
                   A        AA        AG        AC        AT         G \
cg00050873  0.216667  0.041667  0.091667  0.058333  0.008333  0.400000   
cg00212031  0.216667  0.041667  0.100000  0.050000  0.016667  0.391667   
cg00213748  0.183333  0.016667  0.075000  0.050000  0.041667  0.416667   
cg00214611  0.141667  0.025000  0.091667  0.016667  0.000000  0.400000   
cg00455876  0.150000  0.025000  0.083333  0.033333  0.008333  0.425000   
cg01707559  0.108333  0.016667  0.058333  0.008333  0.016667  0.291667   
cg02004872  0.133333  0.000000  0.075000  0.025000  0.033333  0.325000   
cg02011394  0.175000  0.016667  0.066667  0.075000  0.008333  0.258333   
cg02050847  0.175000  0.025000  0.050000  0.033333  0.058333  0.241667   
cg02233190  0.225000  0.033333  0.133333  0.008333  0.033333  0.316667
...
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363890/9439097

Answer (score 0):

Try `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['Forward_Sequence'].apply(freqcount).to_list(), df.index))
```

Comment: This did not really give the expected result in my case. I found the 'correct way to do it' anyway in another answer, but thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `to_list()` instead of `values`. Your answer works fine as well.