# How to populate 2 columns in DataFrame with same "def" function?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have a data frame that has a date column, what I need is to create another 2 columns with the "start of week date" and "end of week date". The reason for this is that I will then need to group by an "isoweek" column... but also keep this two-column "start_of_week_date" and "end_of_week_date"

I've created the below function:

```
def myfunc(dt, option):

wkday = dt.isoweekday()

if option == 'start':
    delta = datetime.timedelta(1 - wkday)
elif option == 'end':
    delta = datetime.timedelta(7 - wkday)
else:
    raise TypeError
    
return date + delta
```

Now I don't know how I would use the above function to populate the columns.

Probably don't even need my function to get what I need... which is... I have a DF that has the below columns

\>>> date, isoweek, qty

I will need to change it to:

\>>> isoweek, start_of_week_date, end_of_week_date, qty

this would then make my data go from 1.8 million rows to 300 thousand rows :D

can someone help me?

thank you

Comment: Hey! Does this help you? [Apply pandas function to column to create multiple new columns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be builtin functions that one can use and i can see one of the answers proposes such.

However, if you wish to **apply your own function** (which is perfectly acceptable) then could use the `apply` with `lambda`.

Here is an example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

# an example dataframe
d = {'some date':[1,2,3,4],
    'other data':[2,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


# user defined function from the question
def myfunc(dt, option):

    wkday = dt.isoweekday()

    if option == 'start':
        delta = datetime.timedelta(1 - wkday)
    elif option == 'end':
        delta = datetime.timedelta(7 - wkday)
    else:
        raise TypeError
        
    return date + delta


df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(df['some data'], df['other data']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand correctly, Refer this [dt.weekday](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html) for caculating week start & week end, here I've used 6 for 'Sunday' if you need any other day as weekend then give the appropriate number.

The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6

```
df['start_of_week_date'] = df['Date'] - df['Date'].dt.weekday.astype('timedelta64[D]')
df['end_of_week_date'] = df['Date'] + (6 - df['Date'].dt.weekday).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```