# Is pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg an efficient solution for calculating multiple columns by group?

Tags: python, performance, aggregate

Suppose you have a `pandas.DataFrame` like this one:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import exp, log10

df = pd.DataFrame({'S' : ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                   'ID': ['ID3', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID4', 'ID4', 'ID1'],
                   'M' : ['Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X'],                   
                   'V' : ['<1', '<0.5', 3, '>10', 7, 6]
                })

df

#   S   ID  M     V
#0  C  ID3  Y    <1
#1  A  ID1  X  <0.5
#2  A  ID2  X     3
#3  B  ID4  Y   >10
#4  B  ID4  Z     7
#5  A  ID1  X     6
```

and a dictionary that maps each `M` to a function of x, like:

```
M_to_transf_dict = {'X' : 'x', 'Y' : 'exp(x)', 'Z' : 'log10(x)'}
```

This is what you need to do:

- split `V` into the numerical part (`V_u`) and qualifier (`V_c`: '<', '>', if not already numerical or interpretable as such)
- group by `S, M`, and for each group:

  - calculate the mean `V_mean`, count `V_N` and sample standard deviation `V_sample_sd` of `V_u`
  - make the comma-separated list of unique `ID`'s and store the result into `ID`
  - find the most frequent '<' or '>' qualifier in `V_c` and store the result into `V_mean_c`
  - apply the function of x corresponding to each `M` to `V_mean` and store the result into `TV_mean`
  - apply `V_mean_c` on `V_mean` and `TV_mean`, when '<' or '>'

After many trials, I put together something that seems to work, but I have doubts regarding performance.
I saw some posts (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236684/apply-pandas-function-to-column-to-create-multiple-new-columns)) questioning the use of `.apply`, and indeed from some tests it appears that handling the splitting of `V` as an external map followed by column assignment is much faster than `.apply`:

```
def unc(v):
    try:
        u = float(v)
        c = "="
    except ValueError:
        v = str(v)
        u = float(v[1:])
        c = v[0]
    except:
        u = pd.NA
        c = "="
    return [u, c]

%timeit df[['V_u', 'V_c']] = df.apply(lambda row : unc(row['V']), axis = 1, result_type = 'expand')
# 698 µs ± 5.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%%timeit
uc = df['V'].map(unc)
u = [uci[0] for uci in uc.values]
c = [uci[1] for uci in uc.values]
df['V_u'] = u
df['V_c'] = c
# 129 µs ± 3.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

%%timeit
uc = df['V'].map(unc)
u, c = [], []
for uci in uc:
    u.append(uci[0])
    c.append(uci[1])
df['V_u'] = u
df['V_c'] = c
# 124 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

(Note that I remade `df` before each `timeit`).

For the other operations I described, except the last two, I used `.groupby.agg` with named aggregation:

```
def majority(c_list):
    c_list = list(c_list)
    Nlt = c_list.count('<')
    Ngt = c_list.count('>')
    if Nlt + Ngt == 0:
        c = '='
    else:
        c = sorted(zip([Nlt, Ngt], ['<','>']))[1][1]
    return c

%%timeit
df_summary_by_S_M = df.groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False).agg(
                    ID = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'ID', aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(np.unique(x))),
                    V_mean = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'mean'),
                    V_mean_c = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_c', aggfunc = majority),
                    V_N = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'count'),
                    V_sample_sd = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'std')
)
# 4.17 ms ± 61.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

df_summary_by_S_M

#   S  M       ID     V_mean V_mean_c  V_N  V_sample_sd
#0  A  X  ID1,ID2   3.166667        <    3     2.753785
#1  B  Y      ID4  10.000000        >    1          NaN
#2  B  Z      ID4   7.000000        =    1          NaN
#3  C  Y      ID3   1.000000        <    1          NaN
```

I don't know how to place this timing, especially because I imagine `.agg` is a form of `.apply`, so I might not be using the best possible approach, having seen the previous results.
On a real dataset I am handling, with about 450 K records that are reduced to 230 K by grouping, this aggregation takes about 1 minute.
I am going to have to handle much larger datasets, and this might become an issue.

**Would anyone be able to suggest a more efficient/performant approach to do the grouped calculations I described?**
Or is this thought to be state-of-the-art performance for this kind of operation? I really have no benchmarks to judge that, hence my asking the question here.

For the last two steps, I think I will use list comprehensions, like:

```
%timeit df_summary_by_S_M['TV_mean'] = [eval(t) for x, t in \
    zip(df_summary_by_S_M['V_mean'], df_summary_by_S_M['M'].map(M_to_transf_dict))]
# 326 µs ± 5.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

df_summary_by_S_M

#   S  M       ID     V_mean V_mean_c  V_N  V_sample_sd       TV_mean
#0  A  X  ID1,ID2   3.166667        <    3     2.753785      3.166667
#1  B  Y      ID4  10.000000        >    1          NaN  22026.465795
#2  B  Z      ID4   7.000000        =    1          NaN      0.845098
#3  C  Y      ID3   1.000000        <    1          NaN      2.718282
```

and:

```
df_summary_by_S_M['V_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df_summary_by_S_M['V_mean_c'], df_summary_by_S_M['V_mean'])]

df_summary_by_S_M['TV_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df_summary_by_S_M['V_mean_c'], df_summary_by_S_M['TV_mean'])]

df_summary_by_S_M

#   S  M       ID               V_mean V_mean_c  V_N  V_sample_sd  \
#0  A  X  ID1,ID2  <3.1666666666666665        <    3     2.753785   
#1  B  Y      ID4                >10.0        >    1          NaN   
#2  B  Z      ID4                  7.0        =    1          NaN   
#3  C  Y      ID3                 <1.0        <    1          NaN   

#               TV_mean  
#0  <3.1666666666666665  
#1  >22026.465794806718  
#2             0.845098  
#3   <2.718281828459045
```

Again, unless someone can suggest a more efficient alternative(?).

---

**EDIT** trying out @mozway's code

Original code, all operations timed together.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from math import exp, log10

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'S' : ['C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A'],
                   'ID': ['ID3', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'ID4', 'ID4', 'ID1'],
                   'M' : ['Y', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X'],                   
                   'V' : ['<1', '<0.5', 3, '>10', 7, 6]
                })

M_to_transf_dict = {'X' : 'x', 'Y' : 'exp(x)', 'Z' : 'log10(x)'}

def unc(v):
    try:
        u = float(v)
        c = "="
    except ValueError:
        v = str(v)
        u = float(v[1:])
        c = v[0]
    except:
        u = pd.NA
        c = "="
    return [u, c]

def majority(c_list):
    c_list = list(c_list)
    Nlt = c_list.count('<')
    Ngt = c_list.count('>')
    if Nlt + Ngt == 0:
        c = '='
    else:
        c = sorted(zip([Nlt, Ngt], ['<','>']))[1][1]
    return c

%%timeit
df = df0.copy()

uc = df['V'].map(unc)
u, c = [], []
for uci in uc:
    u.append(uci[0])
    c.append(uci[1])
df['V_u'] = u
df['V_c'] = c

df = df.groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False).agg(
                    ID = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'ID', aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(np.unique(x))),
                    V_mean = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'mean'),
                    V_mean_c = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_c', aggfunc = majority),
                    V_N = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'count'),
                    V_sample_sd = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'std')
)

df['TV_mean'] = [eval(t) for x, t in \
    zip(df['V_mean'], df['M'].map(M_to_transf_dict))]
df['V_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df['V_mean_c'], df['V_mean'])]
df['TV_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df['V_mean_c'], df['TV_mean'])]
```

Result:

```
# 5.29 ms ± 100 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

@mozway's code.

```
def majority(s):
    mode = s.mode()
    return '=' if len(mode)>1 else mode.iloc[0]

M_dic = {'Y' : np.exp, 'Z' : np.log10}

df = df0.copy()

%%timeit
(df
 .join(df['V']
       .str.extract('(?P<V_c>\D)?(?P<V_u>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
       .astype({'V_u': float}).fillna({'V_c': '=', 'V_u': df['V']})
      )
 .assign(TV=lambda d: d.groupby('M')['V_u'].apply(lambda g: M_dic[g.name](g) if g.name in M_dic else g))
 .groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False)
 .agg(**{'ID': ('ID', lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())),
         'V_mean': ('V_u', 'mean'),
         'V_mean_c': ('V_c', majority), ## FIXME
         'V_N': ('V_u', 'count'),
         'V_sample_sd': ('V_u', 'std'),
         'TV_mean': ('TV', 'mean'),
 })
 .assign(TV_mean=lambda d: d['V_mean_c'].mask(d['V_mean_c'].eq('='), '')+d['TV_mean'].astype(str))
)
```

Result:

```
# 8.05 ms ± 259 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

**EDIT 2** trying again, on a more realistic simulated dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import default_rng
from math import exp, log10

# Simulate dataset to process
rng = default_rng(12345)

S = rng.choice(range(250000), 450000)
ID = S.copy()
S = [f"S_{Si}" for Si in S]
ID = [f"ID_{IDi}" for IDi in ID]
pM = [np.sqrt(1+i) for i in range(100)]
pM = pM / np.sum(pM)
M = rng.choice(range(100), 450000, p = pM)
M_to_transf_dict = dict()
for i in range(0,10):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'exp(x)'
for i in range(10,30):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'x'
for i in range(30,100):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'log10(x)'
M = [f"M_{Mi}" for Mi in M]
V = rng.random(450000)
Q = rng.choice(['', '<', '>'], 450000, p = [0.9, 0.05, 0.05])
V = [f"{q}{v}" for q, v in zip(Q, V)]
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'S' : S, 'ID' : ID, 'M' : M, 'V' : V})
```

Original code:

```
def unc(v):
    try:
        u = float(v)
        c = "="
    except ValueError:
        v = str(v)
        u = float(v[1:])
        c = v[0]
    except:
        u = pd.NA
        c = "="
    return [u, c]

def majority(c_list):
    c_list = list(c_list)
    Nlt = c_list.count('<')
    Ngt = c_list.count('>')
    if Nlt + Ngt == 0:
        c = '='
    else:
        c = sorted(zip([Nlt, Ngt], ['<','>']))[1][1]
    return c

%%timeit
df = df0.copy()

uc = df['V'].map(unc)
u, c = [], []
for uci in uc:
    u.append(uci[0])
    c.append(uci[1])
df['V_u'] = u
df['V_c'] = c

df = df.groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False).agg(
                    ID = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'ID', aggfunc = lambda x : ','.join(np.unique(x))),
                    V_mean = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'mean'),
                    V_mean_c = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_c', aggfunc = majority),
                    V_N = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'count'),
                    V_sample_sd = pd.NamedAgg(column = 'V_u', aggfunc = 'std')
)

df['TV_mean'] = [eval(t) for x, t in \
    zip(df['V_mean'], df['M'].map(M_to_transf_dict))]
df['V_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df['V_mean_c'], df['V_mean'])]
df['TV_mean'] = [c + str(v) if c != '=' else v for c, v in \
    zip(df['V_mean_c'], df['TV_mean'])]
```

Result:

```
# 20 s ± 289 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

@mozway's code (`M_dic` changed according to the new set of `M`'s):

```
def majority(s):
    mode = s.mode()
    return '=' if len(mode)>1 else mode.iloc[0]

M_dic = dict()
for k in M_to_transf_dict:
    if M_to_transf_dict[k] == 'log10(x)':
        M_dic[k] = np.log10
    elif M_to_transf_dict[k] == 'exp(x)':
        M_dic[k] = np.exp

df = df0.copy()

%%timeit
(df
 .join(df['V']
       .str.extract('(?P<V_c>\D)?(?P<V_u>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
       .astype({'V_u': float}).fillna({'V_c': '=', 'V_u': df['V']})
      )
 .assign(TV=lambda d: d.groupby('M')['V_u'].apply(lambda g: M_dic[g.name](g) if g.name in M_dic else g))
 .groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False)
 .agg(**{'ID': ('ID', lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())),
         'V_mean': ('V_u', 'mean'),
         'V_mean_c': ('V_c', majority), ## FIXME
         'V_N': ('V_u', 'count'),
         'V_sample_sd': ('V_u', 'std'),
         'TV_mean': ('TV', 'mean'),
 })
 .assign(TV_mean=lambda d: d['V_mean_c'].mask(d['V_mean_c'].eq('='), '')+d['TV_mean'].astype(str))
)
```

Result:

```
# 52.3 s ± 436 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**EDIT 3** trying again, after simulating a dataset with duplicated `{S, M}` entries.

```
rng = default_rng(12345)

S = rng.choice(range(200000), 225000)
ID = S.copy()
S = [f"S_{Si}" for Si in S]
ID = [f"ID_{IDi}" for IDi in ID]
pM = [np.sqrt(1+i) for i in range(100)]
pM = pM / np.sum(pM)
M = rng.choice(range(100), 225000, p = pM)
M_to_transf_dict = dict()
for i in range(0,10):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'exp(x)'
for i in range(10,30):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'x'
for i in range(30,100):
    M_to_transf_dict[f"M_{i}"] = 'log10(x)'
M = [f"M_{Mi}" for Mi in M]
S = S + S
ID = ID + ID
M = M + M
V = rng.random(450000)
Q = rng.choice(['', '<', '>'], 450000, p = [0.9, 0.05, 0.05])
V = [f"{q}{v}" for q, v in zip(Q, V)]
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'S' : S, 'ID' : ID, 'M' : M, 'V' : V})
```

Original code:

```
10.6 s ± 154 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

@mozway's code:

```
25.8 s ± 550 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

(and the output looks different).

Comment: Can you provide some code to generate a reproducible 450k rows example for timing? If you use random values, ensure to run `np.random.seed(0)` for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is slow due to loops, `apply` and `eval`.

Here is a faster approach (**provided your groups are of sufficient size**):

```
def majority(s):
    mode = s.mode()
    return '=' if len(mode)>1 else mode.iloc[0]

M_dic = {'Y' : np.exp, 'Z' : np.log10}

(df
 .join(df['V']
       .str.extract('(?P<V_c>\D)?(?P<V_u>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
       .astype({'V_u': float}).fillna({'V_c': '=', 'V_u': df['V']})
      )
 .assign(TV=lambda d: d.groupby('M')['V_u'].apply(lambda g: M_dic[g.name](g) if g.name in M_dic else g))
 .groupby(['S','M'], as_index = False)
 .agg(**{'ID': ('ID', lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())),
         'V_mean': ('V_u', 'mean'),
         'V_mean_c': ('V_c', majority), ## FIXME
         'V_N': ('V_u', 'count'),
         'V_sample_sd': ('V_u', 'std'),
         'TV_mean': ('TV', 'mean'),
 })
 .assign(TV_mean=lambda d: d['V_mean_c'].mask(d['V_mean_c'].eq('='), '')+d['TV_mean'].astype(str))
)
```

output:

```
   S  M       ID     V_mean V_mean_c  V_N  V_sample_sd              TV_mean
0  A  X  ID1,ID2   3.166667        =    3     2.753785   3.1666666666666665
1  B  Y      ID4  10.000000        >    1          NaN  >22026.465794806718
2  B  Z      ID4   7.000000        =    1          NaN   0.8450980400142568
3  C  Y      ID3   1.000000        <    1          NaN   <2.718281828459045
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway ; there are a lot of very interesting points to learn from your code. Performance-wise, however, my timeit tests result in slightly longer time than with my own code. I will post them shortly.

Comment: @user6376297 then please provide code to generate such example. In my own testing this code ran in ~40ms vs >1s for yours on a test DataFrame of ~60k rows.

Comment: I posted the test. I tested it on this small example. The type of data I am using is not so easy to simulate, it is quite peculiar. But I take your point, I know that sometimes the performance on a small dataset is not indicative, e.g. because not all processes scale in the same way. So I will see if I can make a simulation of my larger data. BTW the output column V_mean is missing the qualifier in your output.

Comment: You must test on a large example, it is expected to be slower on small datasets

Comment: Done. Unfortunately the conclusion is still the same. In fact however I think some parts of your approach would be faster than mine. It would be interesting to know the time taken by each operation. In R there is something that does that (can't remember the package name now).

Comment: I know why, most of your groups have only 1 item: `{1: 441097, 2: 4420, 3: 21}`, so using `groupby` in this case is equivalent to a loop. Your dataset is just bad for this kind of approach ;)

Comment: OK. In my real data, the most frequent V_N is 2, but I was not sure how to impose that in the simulation. BTW the R package I was thinking of was profvis. https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html . I wonder if there is any python equivalent. Maybe https://www.researchgate.net/post/Could_anyone_suggest_the_profiling_packages_in_python_which_similar_to_profvis_package_in_R