# Subtracting numbers from 2 dataframe columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a beginner at Python and have searched the forum for the answer to my question without success.

I have a matrix and would like to subtract the numbers from one column from the numbers from another column and create a new column with the result.

I tried:

```
df['new column]=df['column 1']-df['column 2']
```

my output is: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

so then I tried to convert these columns to integers before performing subtraction with the following line:

```
df['column 2']=df['column 2'].astype(int)
```

my output is: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

(I have some NaN in my dataframe).  I then tried to replace all of the NaN with
an empty string using the following code:

```
def remove_nan(s):
    import math
    """ remove np.nan"""
    if math.isnan(s) == True:
        s.replace( np.nan,"")
    else:
        return s

df['column 1'] = df.apply(remove_nan, axis=0)
```

My output is: TypeError: `("cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>", 'occurred at index ID Number')`

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide insight as to where I am making errors.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You can look for answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118111/apply-function-to-each-row-of-pandas-dataframe-to-create-two-new-columns

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to convert to numbers with parameter `errors='coerce'` to give `nan` when it isn't a number

Consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('456 8'), B=list('1 345')))

print(df)

   A  B
0  4  1
1  5   
2  6  3
3     4
4  8  5
```

After `pd.to_numeric`

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

print(df)

     A    B
0  4.0  1.0
1  5.0  NaN
2  6.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0
4  8.0  5.0
```

Now we can do our column math

```
df['C'] = df.A - df.B

print(df)

     A    B    C
0  4.0  1.0  3.0
1  5.0  NaN  NaN
2  6.0  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0  NaN
4  8.0  5.0  3.0
```

If you want to assume missing values are zero

```
df['C'] = df.A.sub(df.B, fill_value=0)

print(df)



    A    B    C
0  4.0  1.0  3.0
1  5.0  NaN  5.0
2  6.0  3.0  3.0
3  NaN  4.0 -4.0
4  8.0  5.0  3.0
```