# Returning multiple columns with pandas apply and user-defined functions

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions, multiple-columns, apply

Say I have a function:

```
def fn(x)
    y = x ** 2
    z = x ** 3
    return y, z
```

And I want to use `df['x'].apply(lambda x: fn(x))` to return both `y` and `z` in separate columns. Is there a good way to do this by still using `fn(x)`? In reality, my function will be much more complicated - so I only want to run it once within the apply and assign `output[0]`, `output[1]`, etc to individual columns.

Comment: I think you can just write `df["y"], df["z"] = zip(*df["x"].apply(fn))`, as done in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356501/pandas-create-two-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-values-calculated-from-a-pre/).

Comment: Perfect - I think this works actually. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

How about this method? (n.b., I edited this answer in light of the comment below) so the apply step could take a single function with shared calculations and return the required series for the merge step.

```
data = {'state':['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'], 'year':[2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],'pop':[1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year','state','pop'])
def fn(x,head1,head2):
    y = x ** 2
    z = x ** 3
    return pd.Series({head1:y, head2:z}) 
frame = frame.merge(frame['pop'].apply(lambda s: fn(s,'xsqr','xcube')), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Results:

```
   year   state  pop   xcube   xsqr
0  2000    Ohio  1.5   3.375   2.25
1  2001    Ohio  1.7   4.913   2.89
2  2002    Ohio  3.6  46.656  12.96
3  2001  Nevada  2.4  13.824   5.76
4  2002  Nevada  2.9  24.389   8.41
```

Comment: Thanks BKay - the issue is I need to use fn(x) and not individual calculations, e.g. s**2 and s**3. fn(x) is pretty complex, so I can't isolate the computation for y and z respectively.