# Pandas DataFrame apply() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I just started poking around Python and while I am very excited, it seems that I am far from pythonian thinking.

Here is an example of approach, which has word 'suboptimal' all over.
While this is sufficient for my relatively small dataset, I am wondering how can I write it better way?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

# create sample log data frame
lg = pd.DataFrame(['Access violation at address 00A97...',
                   'Try to edit the splines or change...',
                   'Access violation at address 00F2B...',
                   'Please make sure the main electro...'], columns=['lg_msg'])

# define message classification
err_messages = [['Access violation', 'ACC-VIOL', 'PROG'],
                ['Please make sure th', 'ELE-NOT-PLACED', 'MOD'],
                ['Try to edit the splines', 'TRY-EDIT-SPLINES', 'MOD']]                

# lookup code
def message_code(msg_text):
    for msg in err_messages:
        if msg_text.startswith(msg[0]):
            return msg[1]
    return ''

# lookup type
def message_type(msg_text):
    for msg in err_messages:
        if msg_text.startswith(msg[0]):
            return msg[2]
    return ''               

lg['msg_code'] = lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_code(x))
lg['msg_type'] = lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_type(x))
```

I tried creating a single function to calculate log entry code and type at once:

```
def message_code_type(msg_text):
    for msg in err_messages:
        if msg_text.startswith(msg[0]):
            return (msg[1], msg[2])
    return ('', '')

lg['msg_code'], lg['msg_type'] = lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_code_type(x))
```

but getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-72f97d857539> in <module>()
----> 1 lg['msg_code'], lg['msg_code'] = lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_code_type(x))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Is there any way to not traverse the dataframe twice?

Any feedback will be appreciated.

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jan 29 2016, 15:01:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

pd.__version__
'0.17.1'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this using [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html)  from the itertools module:

```
from itertools import izip
lg['msg_code'], lg['msg_code'] = izip(*lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_code_type(x)))

In [21]:    lg
Out[21]:
    lg_msg  msg_code
0   Access violation at address 00A97...    PROG
1   Try to edit the splines or change...    MOD
2   Access violation at address 00F2B...    PROG
3   Please make sure the main electro...    MOD
```

Sorry, thats for 2.7, you should just be able to use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
lg['msg_code'], lg['msg_type'] = zip(*lg['lg_msg'].apply(lambda x:  message_code_type(x)))

    lg_msg  msg_code    msg_type
0   Access violation at address 00A97...    ACC-VIOL    PROG
1   Try to edit the splines or change...    TRY-EDIT-SPLINES    MOD
2   Access violation at address 00F2B...    ACC-VIOL    PROG
3   Please make sure the main electro...    ELE-NOT-PLACED  MOD
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that!  One thing... my mistake, the two target columns have the same name, which results in a single msg_code column.  Already edited my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no itertools for my environment
`[Anaconda3] C:\Users\[snip]>pip install itertools
Collecting itertools
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement itertools (from versions: )  
No matching distribution found for itertools`

Comment: you don't have to import itertools to use `zip` in python3, it's built-in.  Check out the example in the second link I posted.  This, in particular: `x2, y2 = zip(*zip(x, y))`.  Here's [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356501/pandas-create-two-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-values-calculated-from-a-pre) that uses `zip` and `map`.