# Too many values to unpack using apply()

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code I have:

```
def f(row):
  if row['CountInBedDate'] == 1 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 1:
    SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
    InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']
    OutBedTimeFinal = row['OutBedTime']
  else:
    SleepDate = -1
    InBedTimeFinal = -1
    OutBedTimeFinal = -1
  return SleepDate, InBedTimeFinal, OutBedTimeFinal

s1['SleepDate'], s1['InBedTimeFinal'], s1['OutBedTimeFinal'] = s1.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I would like to create 3 new columns with apply() but there is

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

If I use this, only one column was created with 3 values combined:

```
s1['SleepDate', 'InBedTimeFinal', 'OutBedTimeFinal'] = s1.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Could you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Could you give more information about `s1`? Looks like `s1.apply(f, axis=1)` returns more that 3 values.

Comment: s1 is a dataframe with many columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame apply() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373223/pandas-dataframe-apply-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack-expected-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `f` is your real function, then you should consider using [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) instead of apply, it will be way faster.

```
s1[['SleepDate', 'InBedTimeFinal', 'OutBedTimeFinal']] = \
           s1[['DateInBed','InBedTime','OutBedTime']].where(s1['CountInBedDate'].eq(1), other=-1)
```

Note it seems that in your function you check twice that CountInBedDate is equal to 1

If you want to use apply, then you can try:

```
s1[['SleepDate', 'InBedTimeFinal', 'OutBedTimeFinal']] = \
               pd.DataFrame(s1.apply(f, axis=1).tolist(), s1.index)
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake. I have changed that to CountOutBedDate. I would like to use if else because I will add other conditions to the codes. This is just a small part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f` returns tuple for each row, so `apply` stacks tuples to series. You need `f` return series and unpack on ndarray of the result of `apply`

```
def f(row):
  if row['CountInBedDate'] == 1 and row['CountOutBedDate'] == 1:
    SleepDate = row['DateInBed']
    InBedTimeFinal = row['InBedTime']
    OutBedTimeFinal = row['OutBedTime']
  else:
    SleepDate = -1
    InBedTimeFinal = -1
    OutBedTimeFinal = -1
  return pd.Series([SleepDate, InBedTimeFinal, OutBedTimeFinal]) #change here

s1['SleepDate'], s1['InBedTimeFinal'], s1['OutBedTimeFinal'] = s1.apply(f, axis=1).T.values
```

Comment: yep the other option :)

Comment: @Ben.T: Thanks :) +1