# Create Two new Columns from two existing column using a function which takes two parameters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a similar problem like this, but this answer couldn't solve my problem
[Pandas: create two new columns in a dataframe with values calculated from a pre-existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356501/pandas-create-two-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-with-values-calculated-from-a-pre) .
I have a function which takes two parameters and return two different values in `float` Original dataframes are also in `float`

```
def FunctionName (a, b):
   some calculations---
   return x, y
```

I have  `df` and I want to use function `FunctionName` so that I will have two new Series from those existing Series `df['A], df['B]`

```
df['A], df['B]
df['A_new'], df['B_new'] = df[['A'], df['B']].apply(FunctionName)
```

gives me an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I also tried 
`df['A_new'], df['B_new'] = FunctionName ( df['A'], df['B'])` gives me an error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I want to use return X values to `df['A_new']` and Y values to `df['B_new']`

Can someone please tell, what i am missing here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need parameter `axis=1` to [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processes by rows with lambda function for define columns bynames and return `Series` for new columns - added by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'B':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'C':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  4  7  1
1  5  8  3
2  4  9  5
3  5  4  7
4  5  2  1
5  4  3  0

def FunctionName (a, b):
   x = a * 5
   y = b * 7
   return pd.Series([x, y], index=['A_new','B_new'])

df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x: FunctionName(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1))
print (df)
   A  B  C  A_new  B_new
0  4  7  1     20     49
1  5  8  3     25     56
2  4  9  5     20     63
3  5  4  7     25     28
4  5  2  1     25     14
5  4  3  0     20     21
```

---

```
def FunctionName (a, b):
   x = a * 5
   y = b * 7
   return pd.Series([x, y])

df[['A_new', 'B_new']] = df.apply(lambda x: FunctionName(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C  A_new  B_new
0  4  7  1     20     49
1  5  8  3     25     56
2  4  9  5     20     63
3  5  4  7     25     28
4  5  2  1     25     14
5  4  3  0     20     21
```